# Python JSON serialize a Decimal object

Tags: python, json, floating-point, decimal

I have a `Decimal('3.9')` as part of an object, and wish to encode this to a JSON string which should look like `{'x': 3.9}`. I don't care about precision on the client side, so a float is fine.

Is there a good way to serialize this? JSONDecoder doesn't accept Decimal objects, and converting to a float beforehand yields `{'x': 3.8999999999999999}` which is wrong, and will be a big waste of bandwidth.

Comment: related Python bug: [json encoder unable to handle decimal](http://bugs.python.org/issue16535)

Comment: 3.8999999999999999 is no more wrong than 3.4 is.  0.2 has no exact float representation.

Comment: @Jasen 3.89999999999 is about 12.8% more wrong than 3.4 is. The JSON standard is only about serialisation and notation, not implementation. Using IEEE754 is not part of the raw JSON spec, it is only the most common way to implement it. An implementation that uses only precise decimal arithmetic is completely (in fact, even more strictly) conforming.

Comment:  _less_ wrong. ironic.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

How about subclassing `json.JSONEncoder`?

```
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            # wanted a simple yield str(o) in the next line,
            # but that would mean a yield on the line with super(...),
            # which wouldn't work (see my comment below), so...
            return (str(o) for o in [o])
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)
```

Then use it like so:

```
json.dumps({'x': decimal.Decimal('5.5')}, cls=DecimalEncoder)
```

Comment: Simplejson has native support for Decimals - see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960516/python-json-serialize-a-decimal-object/3148376#3148376

Comment: Can't you just `return (str(o),)` instead? `[o]` is a list with only 1 element, why bother looping over it?

Comment: @Mark: `return (str(o),)` would return tuple of length 1, while code in the answer returns generator of length 1. See the [iterencode() docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.iterencode)

Comment: This implementation doesn't work anymore. Elias Zamaria's one is the one working on the same style.

Comment: This worked well for me for a bit, but I had a few issues with the `super` call due to the class getting reloaded (within a webserver and using a lot of pickle-based caching). Replacing it with `super(self.__class__, self)._iterencode(o, markers)`, seemed to fix it.

Comment: @Abgan, still `iter((o, ))` is probably faster. timeit says it's 3 times faster in Python 3.5.

Comment: My **encode and decode** [answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678946/python-3-x-cannot-serialize-decimal-to-json/53752866#53752866)

Comment: For the current version of `json`, the `_iterencode` function should be replaced with `default` without the `markers` keyword argument.

Comment: Its getting me this error: TypeError: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fd42908da20> is not JSON serializable

Comment: This is solution not working for
`{'merchant': {'store': [Decimal('1')]}}`
use
`return str(o)`
instead of 
`return (str(o) for o in [o])`

Comment: Have you tried your code? It results in the value in JSON being a string and not a float, as TS wanted. I have just tried it and I get `"batchId": "31705"` instead of `"batchId": 31705`.

Answer (score 277):

[Simplejson 2.1](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson) and higher has native support for Decimal type:

```
>>> import simplejson as json

>>> json.dumps(Decimal('3.9'), use_decimal=True)
'3.9'
```

Note that `use_decimal` is `True` by default:

```
def dumps(obj, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True, check_circular=True,
    allow_nan=True, cls=None, indent=None, separators=None,
    encoding='utf-8', default=None, use_decimal=True,
    namedtuple_as_object=True, tuple_as_array=True,
    bigint_as_string=False, sort_keys=False, item_sort_key=None,
    for_json=False, ignore_nan=False, **kw):
```

So:

```
>>> json.dumps(Decimal('3.9'))
'3.9'
```

Hopefully, this feature will be included in standard library.

Comment: Hmm, for me this converts Decimal objects to floats, which is not acceptable. Loss of precision when working with currency, for instance.

Comment: @MatthewSchinckel I think it doesn't. It actually makes a string out of it. And if you feed the resultant string back to `json.loads(s, use_decimal=True)` it gives you back the decimal. No float in entire process. Edited above answer. Hope original poster is fine with it.

Comment: Aha, I think I was not using `use_decimal=True` on the loads, too.

Comment: For me `json.dumps({'a' : Decimal('3.9')}, use_decimal=True)` gives `'{"a": 3.9}'`. Was the goal not `'{"a": "3.9"}'` ?

Comment: @MrJ `"3.9"` is a string, `Decimal('3.9')` is a number, so `{"a": 3.9}` is what is expected.

Comment: This is much better than using the string version of the `Decimal`.

Comment: `simplejson.dumps(decimal.Decimal('2.2'))` also works: no explicit `use_decimal` (tested on simplejson/3.6.0). Another way to load it back is: `json.loads(s, parse_float=Decimal)` i.e., you can read it using stdlib `json` (and old `simplejson` versions are also supported).

Comment: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_decimal'

Comment: @Madeo I have the same issue, python 3.7  i think its because the json an simplejson libraries are different

Comment: I prefer the standard library `default` hook here to handle Decimal as it _makes it explicit how you are handling these_. You can't just assume that the decoder (which might not be another Python app) can handle the higher precision values, you may want to encode to a `{"type": "__decimal__", "value", "string representation of decimal"}` object, for example. These decisions are _domain specific_, because you are stepping outside the confines of the JSON standard.

Comment: @Martjin does the standard library have a means for using `dumps` with Decimal? The 3.11 json module doc shows an float keyword for `loads` only

Answer (score 270):

I would like to let everyone know that I tried Michał Marczyk's answer on my web server that was running Python 2.6.5 and it worked fine. However, I upgraded to Python 2.7 and it stopped working. I tried to think of some sort of way to encode Decimal objects and this is what I came up with:

```
import decimal

class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return str(o)
        return super().default(o)
```

Note that this will convert the decimal to its string representation (e.g.; `"1.2300"`) to a. not lose significant digits and b. prevent rounding errors.

This should hopefully help anyone who is having problems with Python 2.7. I tested it and it seems to work fine. If anyone notices any bugs in my solution or comes up with a better way, please let me know.

Usage example:

```
json.dumps({'x': decimal.Decimal('5.5')}, cls=DecimalEncoder)
```

Comment: Python 2.7 changed the rules for rounding floats so this works. See discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447287/format-floats-with-standard-json-module

Comment: For those of us who can't use simplejson (ie. on Google App Engine) this answer is a Godsend.

Comment: I guess it depends on platform. I'm seeing `{"x": 54.399999999999999}`. Yes, it did not results in error but it is not what was intended.

Comment: Use `unicode` or `str` instead of `float` to ensure precision.

Comment: The problem with 54.3999... was important in Python 2.6.x and older where the conversion float to string did not worked regularly, but the conversion Decimal to str is much more incorrect because it would be serialized as string with double quotes `"54.4"`, not as a number.

Comment: Works in python3

Comment: what 'type' does this return? I'm getting a str type, which isn't ideal

Answer (score 67):

*The native Django option is missing so I'll add it for the next guy/gall that looks for it.*

Starting on Django 1.7.x there is a built-in `DjangoJSONEncoder` that you can get it from `django.core.serializers.json`.

```
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

model_instance = YourModel.object.first()
model_dict = model_to_dict(model_instance)

json.dumps(model_dict, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Presto!

Comment: Although this is great to know, the OP didn't ask about Django?

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave you are 100% correct. I forgot how i got here, but i googled this question with "django" attached to the search term and this came up, after a little more googling, i found the answer and added it here for the next person like me, that stumbles across it

Answer (score 58):

In my Flask app, Which uses python 2.7.11, flask alchemy(with 'db.decimal' types), and Flask Marshmallow ( for 'instant' serializer and deserializer), i had this error, every time i did a GET or POST. The serializer and deserializer, failed to convert  Decimal types into any JSON identifiable format.

I did a  "pip install simplejson", then 
Just by adding

```
import simplejson as json
```

the serializer and deserializer starts to purr again. I did nothing else...
DEciamls are displayed as '234.00' float format.

Comment: Oddly enough, you don't even have to import `simplejson` - just installing it does the trick.  Initially mentioned by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224186/2738164).

Comment: This does not work on me, and still got that `Decimal('0.00') is not JSON serializable`  after installing it via pip. This situation is when you are using both marshmallow and graphene. When a query is called on a rest api, marshmallow works expectedly for decimal fields. However when it is called with graphql it raised an `is not JSON serializable` error.

Comment: Perfect! This works in situations where you're using a module written by someone else whcih you can't easily modify (in my case gspread for using Google Sheets)

Answer (score 41):

I tried switching from simplejson to builtin json for GAE 2.7, and had issues with the decimal. If default returned str(o) there were quotes (because _iterencode calls _iterencode on the results of default), and float(o) would remove trailing 0.

If default returns an object of a class that inherits from float (or anything that calls repr without additional formatting) and has a custom __repr__ method, it seems to work like I want it to.

```
import json
from decimal import Decimal

class fakefloat(float):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._value)

def defaultencode(o):
    if isinstance(o, Decimal):
        # Subclass float with custom repr?
        return fakefloat(o)
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

json.dumps([10.20, "10.20", Decimal('10.20')], default=defaultencode)
'[10.2, "10.20", 10.20]'
```

Comment: Nice! This makes sure the decimal value ends up in the JSON as a Javascript float, without having Python first round it to the nearest float value.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in recent Python 3's. There is now some fast-path code that considers all float-subclasses as floats, and doesn't call repr on them altogether.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, the example works fine on Python 3.6.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu indeed, I don't seem to be able to reproduce the bad behaviour now

Comment: An issue with this answer is that it depends on the fact that the current JSON implementation uses [`float.__repr__` for floats](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.2/Lib/json/encoder.py#L223). On the other hand [`int.__str__` is used for integers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.2/Lib/json/encoder.py#L271), so it's possible that things might change for floats.

Comment: The solution stopped working since v3.5.2rc1, see https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/e0805cf10ea84b44a13ad5649267edba7cb83ee9. There is `float.__repr__` hardcoded (that looses precision), and `fakefloat.__repr__` is not called at all.

The solution above does work properly for python3 up to 3.5.1, if fakefloat has additional method `def __float__(self): return self`.

Answer (score 29):

**For Django users**:

Recently came across `TypeError: Decimal('2337.00') is not JSON serializable`
while JSON encoding i.e. `json.dumps(data)`

**Solution**:

```
# converts Decimal, Datetime, UUIDs to str for Encoding
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder  

json.dumps(response.data, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

But, now the Decimal value will be a string, now we can explicitly set the decimal/float value parser when decoding data, using `parse_float` option in `json.loads`:

```
import decimal 

data = json.loads(data, parse_float=decimal.Decimal) # default is float(num_str)
```

Answer (score 19):

For those who don't want to use a third-party library...  An issue with Elias Zamaria's answer is that it converts to float, which can run into problems.  For example:

```
>>> json.dumps({'x': Decimal('0.0000001')}, cls=DecimalEncoder)
'{"x": 1e-07}'
>>> json.dumps({'x': Decimal('100000000000.01734')}, cls=DecimalEncoder)
'{"x": 100000000000.01733}'
```

The `JSONEncoder.encode()` method lets you return the literal json content, unlike `JSONEncoder.default()`, which has you return a json compatible type (like float) that then gets encoded in the normal way.  The problem with `encode()` is that it (normally) only works at the top level.  But it's still usable, with a little extra work (python 3.x):

```
import json
from collections.abc import Mapping, Iterable
from decimal import Decimal

class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def encode(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Mapping):
            return '{' + ', '.join(f'{self.encode(k)}: {self.encode(v)}' for (k, v) in obj.items()) + '}'
        if isinstance(obj, Iterable) and (not isinstance(obj, str)):
            return '[' + ', '.join(map(self.encode, obj)) + ']'
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return f'{obj.normalize():f}'  # using normalize() gets rid of trailing 0s, using ':f' prevents scientific notation
        return super().encode(obj)
```

Which gives you:

```
>>> json.dumps({'x': Decimal('0.0000001')}, cls=DecimalEncoder)
'{"x": 0.0000001}'
>>> json.dumps({'x': Decimal('100000000000.01734')}, cls=DecimalEncoder)
'{"x": 100000000000.01734}'
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It was exactly what I was looking for.  It outputs as a number but without the loss of precision due to float conversion.  I ran into a little issue because I am using `json.dump` instead of `json.dumps` and you have to override `iterencode` instead of `encode` as explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52939176/json-encoder-different-results-for-json-dump-and-json-dumps).

Comment: Thanks, this was the best solution that I found. Note, that `parse_float` can be used in `json.loads` to restore the python object (all floats will be converted to Decimal): `json.loads(json.dumps({'x': Decimal('0.0000001')}, cls=DecimalEncoder), parse_float=Decimal)`. This is already mentioned in other comments, but I missed that in this solution.

Answer (score 14):

My $.02!

I extend a bunch of the JSON encoder since I am serializing tons of data for my web server. Here's some nice code. Note that it's easily extendable to pretty much any data format you feel like and will reproduce 3.9 as `"thing": 3.9`

```
JSONEncoder_olddefault = json.JSONEncoder.default
def JSONEncoder_newdefault(self, o):
    if isinstance(o, UUID): return str(o)
    if isinstance(o, datetime): return str(o)
    if isinstance(o, time.struct_time): return datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(o))
    if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal): return str(o)
    return JSONEncoder_olddefault(self, o)
json.JSONEncoder.default = JSONEncoder_newdefault
```

Makes my life so much easier...

Comment: This is incorrect: it will reproduce 3.9 as `"thing": "3.9"`.

Comment: @Glyph via JSON standards (of which there are a few...), an unquoted number is a double-precision floating-point, not a decimal number. Quoting it is the only way to guarantee compatibility.

Comment: do you have a citation for this? Every spec I’ve read implies that it’s implementation-dependent.

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave the JSON spec clearly states that a _number_ is a sequence of digits, with an optional _fraction_ and _exponent_. A number in JSON is not double-precision floating point just because some implementations chose to implement it that way.

Answer (score 13):

`3.9` can not be exactly represented in IEEE floats, it will always come as `3.8999999999999999`, e.g. try  `print repr(3.9)`, you can read more about it here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point
http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

So if you don't want float, only option you have to send it as string, and to allow automatic conversion of decimal objects to JSON, do something like this:

```
import decimal
from django.utils import simplejson

def json_encode_decimal(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
        return str(obj)
    raise TypeError(repr(obj) + " is not JSON serializable")

d = decimal.Decimal('3.5')
print simplejson.dumps([d], default=json_encode_decimal)
```

Comment: I know it won't be 3.9 internally once it is parsed on the client, but 3.9 is a valid JSON float.
ie, `json.loads("3.9")` will work, and I would like it to be this

Comment: @Anurag You meant repr(obj) instead of repr(o) in your example.

Comment: Won't this just die if you try and encode something that isn't decimal?

Comment: @nailer, no it won't , you can try that, reason being default raise exception to signal that next handler should be used

Comment: See mikez302's answer - in Python 2.7 or above, this no longer applies.

Comment: In Python 2.7, `print repr(3.9)` will give you `3.9`

Comment: Django no longer has `simplejson` in it's `utils`. This code would no longer work.

Comment: This is exactly why Decimal is a standard library in Python https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 10):

From the [JSON Standard Document](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), as linked in [json.org](https://www.json.org/):

> JSON is agnostic about the semantics of numbers. In any programming language, there can be a variety of
>   number types of various capacities and complements, fixed or floating, binary or decimal. That can make
>   interchange between different programming languages difficult. JSON instead offers only the representation of
>   numbers that humans use: a sequence of digits. All programming languages know how to make sense of digit
>   sequences even if they disagree on internal representations. That is enough to allow interchange.

So it's actually accurate to represent Decimals as numbers (rather than strings) in JSON. Bellow lies a possible solution to the problem.

Define a custom JSON encoder:

```
import json


class CustomJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return float(obj)
        return super(CustomJsonEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

Then use it when serializing your data:

```
json.dumps(data, cls=CustomJsonEncoder)
```

As noted from comments on the other answers, older versions of python might mess up the representation when converting to float, but that's not the case anymore.

To get the decimal back in Python:

```
Decimal(str(value))
```

This solution is hinted in [Python 3.0 documentation on decimals](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/decimal.html):

> To create a Decimal from a float, first convert it to a string.

Comment: This isn't "fixed" in Python 3. Converting to a `float` *necessarily* makes you lose the decimal representation, and *will* lead to discrepancies. If `Decimal` is important to use, I think it is better to use strings.

Comment: I believe it's safe to do this since python 3.1. The loss in precision might be harmful in arithmetic operations, but in the case of JSON encoding, you are merely producing a string display of the value, so the precision is more than enough for most use cases. Everything in JSON is a string already, so putting quotes around the value just defies the JSON spec.

Comment: With that said, I understand the concerns around converting to float. There's probably a different strategy to use with the encoder to produce the wanted display string. Still, I don't think it's worth producing a quoted value.

Comment: @HugoMota " Everything in JSON is a string already, so putting quotes around the value just defies the JSON spec." No: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259.txt -- JSON is a text-based encoding format, but that doesn't mean everything in it is to be interpreted as a string. The spec defines how to encode numbers, separately from strings.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon "JSON is a text-based encoding format" - that's what I meant with "everything is a string". Converting the numbers to string beforehand won't magically preserve precision since it will be a string anyway when it becomes JSON. And according to the spec, numbers don't have quotes around it. **It's the reader's responsibility to preserve precision while reading** (not a quote, just my take on it).

Answer (score 7):

This is what I have, extracted from our class

```
class CommonJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    """
    Common JSON Encoder
    json.dumps(myString, cls=CommonJSONEncoder)
    """

    def default(self, obj):

        if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
            return {'type{decimal}': str(obj)}

class CommonJSONDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):

    """
    Common JSON Encoder
    json.loads(myString, cls=CommonJSONEncoder)
    """

    @classmethod
    def object_hook(cls, obj):
        for key in obj:
            if isinstance(key, six.string_types):
                if 'type{decimal}' == key:
                    try:
                        return decimal.Decimal(obj[key])
                    except:
                        pass

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['object_hook'] = self.object_hook
        super(CommonJSONDecoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Which passes unittest:

```
def test_encode_and_decode_decimal(self):
    obj = Decimal('1.11')
    result = json.dumps(obj, cls=CommonJSONEncoder)
    self.assertTrue('type{decimal}' in result)
    new_obj = json.loads(result, cls=CommonJSONDecoder)
    self.assertEqual(new_obj, obj)

    obj = {'test': Decimal('1.11')}
    result = json.dumps(obj, cls=CommonJSONEncoder)
    self.assertTrue('type{decimal}' in result)
    new_obj = json.loads(result, cls=CommonJSONDecoder)
    self.assertEqual(new_obj, obj)

    obj = {'test': {'abc': Decimal('1.11')}}
    result = json.dumps(obj, cls=CommonJSONEncoder)
    self.assertTrue('type{decimal}' in result)
    new_obj = json.loads(result, cls=CommonJSONDecoder)
    self.assertEqual(new_obj, obj)
```

Comment: `json.loads(myString, cls=CommonJSONEncoder)` comment should be `json.loads(myString, cls=CommonJSONDecoder)`

Comment: object_hook needs a default return value if obj is not decimal.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom JSON encoder as per your requirement.

```
import json
from datetime import datetime, date
from time import time, struct_time, mktime
import decimal

class CustomJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, datetime):
            return str(o)
        if isinstance(o, date):
            return str(o)
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return float(o)
        if isinstance(o, struct_time):
            return datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(o))
        # Any other serializer if needed
        return super(CustomJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
```

The Decoder can be called like this,

```
import json
from decimal import Decimal
json.dumps({'x': Decimal('3.9')}, cls=CustomJSONEncoder)
```

and the output will be:

```
>>'{"x": 3.9}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [stdOrgnlDave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1110687/stdorgnldave) answer I have defined this wrapper that it can be called with optional kinds so the encoder will work only for certain kinds inside your projects. I believe the work should be done inside your code and not to use this "default" encoder since "it is better explicit than implicit", but I understand using this will save some of your time. :-)

```
import time
import json
import decimal
from uuid import UUID
from datetime import datetime

def JSONEncoder_newdefault(kind=['uuid', 'datetime', 'time', 'decimal']):
    '''
    JSON Encoder newdfeault is a wrapper capable of encoding several kinds
    Use it anywhere on your code to make the full system to work with this defaults:
        JSONEncoder_newdefault()  # for everything
        JSONEncoder_newdefault(['decimal'])  # only for Decimal
    '''
    JSONEncoder_olddefault = json.JSONEncoder.default

    def JSONEncoder_wrapped(self, o):
        '''
        json.JSONEncoder.default = JSONEncoder_newdefault
        '''
        if ('uuid' in kind) and isinstance(o, uuid.UUID):
            return str(o)
        if ('datetime' in kind) and isinstance(o, datetime):
            return str(o)
        if ('time' in kind) and isinstance(o, time.struct_time):
            return datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(o))
        if ('decimal' in kind) and isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return str(o)
        return JSONEncoder_olddefault(self, o)
    json.JSONEncoder.default = JSONEncoder_wrapped

# Example
if __name__ == '__main__':
    JSONEncoder_newdefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

I will share what worked for me with flask 2.1.0
When I was creating the dictionary which had to be used from jsonify I used rounding:

```
json_dict['price'] = round(self.price, ndigits=2) if self.price else 0
```

So this way I could return D.DD number or 0 without using some global configuration. And this is nice because some Decimals has to be bigger, like latitude and longitude coordinates.

```
return jsonify(json_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a dictionary containing decimals to the `requests` library (using the `json` keyword argument), you simply need to install `simplejson`:

```
$ pip3 install simplejson    
$ python3
>>> import requests
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> # This won't error out:
>>> requests.post('https://www.google.com', json={'foo': Decimal('1.23')})
```

The reason of the problem is that `requests` uses `simplejson` only if it is present, and falls back to the built-in `json` if it is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that wants a quick solution here is how I removed Decimal from my queries in Django

```
total_development_cost_var = process_assumption_objects.values('total_development_cost').aggregate(sum_dev = Sum('total_development_cost', output_field=FloatField()))
total_development_cost_var = list(total_development_cost_var.values())
```

- Step 1: use , output_field=FloatField() in you r query
- Step 2: use list eg list(total_development_cost_var.values())

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for the answer, it is most probably you have a 'NaN' in your data that you are trying to encode. Because NaN is considered as float by Python.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30216739)

Answer (score 0):

Decimal is not suitable to be converted through:

- `float` due to precision problems
- `str` due to openapi restrictions

We still need direct decimal to a number json serialisation.

Here is our extension of [@tesdal 's fakefloat solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8274307/2319271) (closed in v3.5.2rc1).
It uses fakestr + monkeypatching to avoid quotation and "floatation" of decimals.

```py
import json.encoder
from decimal import Decimal


def encode_fakestr(func):
    def wrap(s):
        if isinstance(s, fakestr):
            return repr(s)
        return func(s)
    return wrap


json.encoder.encode_basestring = encode_fakestr(json.encoder.encode_basestring)
json.encoder.encode_basestring_ascii = encode_fakestr(json.encoder.encode_basestring_ascii)


class fakestr(str):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._value)


class DecimalJsonEncoder(json.encoder.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, Decimal):
            return fakestr(o)
        return super().default(o)


json.dumps([Decimal('1.1')], cls=DecimalJsonEncoder)

[1.1]
```

I don't understand why python developers force us using floats in places where it is not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:---

```
import json
from decimal import *

num = Decimal('8439.67')


class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return str(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


json_str = json.dumps({'number': num}, cls=DecimalEncoder)
print(json_str)
print(type(json_str))

'''
Output:-
{"number": "8439.67"}
<class 'str'>
'''
```

Comment: This is a wrong solution since the value in the JSON is a string, while the TS is expecting the value to be a float.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are enough answers in here but I got here needing a way to convert a list of numpy numbers to rounded decimals ready for export with `simplejson`

```
def encode_floats(nums, decimals=3):
    """
    Convert numpy numbers to ones ready for dumping with simplejson
    useful when you don't want your json exports to be bloated with too many
    significant figures
    :param nums: list of numbers
    :param decimals: number of decimals you want to output
    """
    def convert_to_rounded_dec(num):
        # convert to decimal
        num_dec = Decimal(np.float64(num))
        # create decimal number for quantizing
        round_dec = Decimal("".join(['0.'] + ['0'] * (decimals - 1) + ['1']))
        # actually round the number here
        num_round = num_dec.quantize(round_dec, rounding='ROUND_HALF_UP')
        return num_round
    # apply the function to the list of numbers
    func = (np.vectorize(convert_to_rounded_dec))
    # remove the numpy data type by converting to a list
    return func(nums).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

For whathever reason my requirement was to omit unneccessary 0's, so e.g. `123.0` should become `123`. Also my requirement was to have the json output as number and not as string.

So thanks to Elias Zamarias solution I came up with the following:

```
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            if float(o) == int(o):
                return int(o)
            else:
                return float(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `simplejson` or `ujson`

```
>>> import ujson
>>> import decimal
>>> ujson.dumps(decimal.Decimal(1.23))
'1.23'
>>> ujson.dumps({"w":decimal.Decimal(1.23)}) 
'{"w":1.23}'
>>>
```

Note that ujson is faster than json
https://dev.to/dollardhingra/benchmarking-python-json-serializers-json-vs-ujson-vs-orjson-1o16

Answer (score -2):

This question is old, but there seems to be a better and much simpler solution in Python3 for most use-cases:

```
number = Decimal(0.55)
converted_number = float(number) # Returns: 0.55 (as type float)
```

You can just convert `Decimal` to `float`.

Comment: The question already describes why converting to float is not wanted