# Python/Django QuerySet to list of dicts?

Tags: python, django

This is my code:

```
obj = Object1.objects.get(pk=1)
other_objs = ob1.other_objs.all()
```

other_objs is a ManyToManyField on the Object1 object.

When I execute this code:

```
print other_objs[0]
```

I do not get an other_obj (which should be a dict), I get a string based off the __unicode__ method in the other_obj class.

How can I get the other_obj dict rather than just the unicode string?

Comment: could you explain better you question? is `other_objs` a many to many relation?

Comment: I still don't understand the `dict` part. Why do you need a `dict`?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/62073213/9384511

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`other_objs[0]` will be the first element of query and will not be a dict or string but the django model object, you can access attributes like `other_objs[0].myattr1`, if you want dict you can ask for specifc attributes using `objects.values_list` and then create a dict out of them e.g.

```
attrs = ['id', 'attr1']
values = Object1.objects.values_list(attrs)[0]
obj_dict = dict(zip(attrs, values))
```

or you can use [django serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) is you want to output dict or json etc, but I think you just need an object, and original query is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `.all()`, you're getting a `queryset` (see it as a `list`) of the objects related with your `Object1` object.

So, when you do `other_objs[0]`, you're getting the first related object. And then, when you print it, it calls its `__unicode__` method to actually print the object.