# Django Paginator change object_list

Tags: django, django-pagination

Is there a way to change Paginator object_list without creating new Paginator?

I would like to order the queryset I passed to the Paginator.

Right now I'm creating new Paginator based on the ordered queryset.

Thanks

Comment: `order the queryset` by what?

Comment: did not work.
I tried: page.object_list = page.object_list.order_by('name')
but no change was made.

Comment: it will really not work. you have to order that in the query before it paginate

Comment: so no way to reuse the paginator object?
That means that I would have to access the DB again and to create new paginator right?

Comment: no, you don't have to access the DB again or create new again. Can you post your codes in views

Comment: I could explain what I'm doing - I have an option for sorting the DB results.
Therefore I save the ids of the objects I need and when sorting I just access the DB, getting the objects order them and then create new paginator based on the ordered object

Comment: @catherine: any hints?

Comment: got it: doing it in memory

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after all these years since this question was posted, I am getting it at the top of my google search hit list.  And I have just made a simple test that proves one can change the paginator.object_list (which starts as a Django QuerySet) to a list of dictionaries, and this works seamlessly in the template.  As the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/) says, the object_list can be: "A list, tuple, QuerySet, or other sliceable object with a count() or **len**() method."

So one can reorder the list this way, or, as I need to do, one can add more fields to the dictionary from a second database.  You do need to keep the length of the replacement list to the same length as the original QuerySet, in order to use all the other features of the Paginator object.  Using the QuerySet method values() allows you to retain all the fields very easily (thanks [@David Wolever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/71522/david-wolever) for [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811556/how-do-i-convert-a-django-queryset-into-list-of-dicts))

Here is some code:

```
new_object_list = list(records_from_paginator.object_list.values())
reordered_or_changed_object_list = reorder_or_change_object_list(new_object_list)
records_from_paginator.object_list = reordered_or_changed_object_list
```