# Convert Django queryset to dictionnary in a JSON serialization purpose

Tags: python, json, django, api, serialization

I'm creating an API and I need to return data in a dictionnary format sothat it can be serialized (by the API mechanism).

The code that currently works is something as simple as:

```
def mymethod(self):

    queryset1 = MyClass.objects.get(...) # Ccontains 1 object, easy to deal with
    queryset2 = OtherClass.objects.filter(...) # Contains N objects, hard to deal with !

    return {
        'qs1_result': queryset1.some_attribute # This works well
    }
```

Returning data from queryset1 is easy because there is 1 object. I just pick the attribute I need and it works. Now let's say that in addition, I want to return data from queryset2, where there are many objects, and that I don't need every attributes of the object.

**How would you do that?**

I repeat that I do NOT need to make the serialization myself. I just need to return structured data sothat the serialization can be made.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields

Subset of fields
If you only want a subset of fields to be serialized, you can specify a fields argument to the serializer:

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize('json', SomeModel.objects.all(), fields=('name','size'))
```

In this example, only the name and size attributes of each model will be serialized.

Comment: I must NOT serialize the data myself. I just need to return data in a structured dictionnary.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811556/convert-a-django-queryset-into-list-of-dicts

Comment: Yes thanks I saw it too. It's a first step because it gives me a list of N dicts (1 dict per object in the queryset).