# get dictionary from queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have below query where I want to fetch 'specs' which is a dictionary but the type of envi_dict is a Queryset class. How do I fetch the dictionary from this queryset? Any help is much appreciated.

```
envi_dict = Environment.objects.values('specs')
```

Result

```
<QuerySet [({u'CPU Model': u'Dell', u'RAM': 1000, u'CPU': 400},), ({u'CPU Model': u'Dell', u'RAM': 1000, u'CPU': 400},)]>, <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>, )
```

I tried `Environment.objects.filter(title=item.title).values('specs')` and also `Environment.objects.get('specs')` but I am still getting a queryset.

Edit: Below is `models.py`

```
class CommonModel(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True)
    requirements = JSONField(default = {})
    specs = JSONField(default= {})
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
       abstract = True

    def update(self):
        self.updated_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Estimate(CommonModel):

    gp_code = models.TextField(default='Unknown')
    inputs = models.TextField(blank=True)
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Environment(CommonModel):

    estimate = models.ForeignKey(Estimate,related_name='environments')
    logic = PythonCodeField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

Comment: Please share the model class

Comment: Why do you need a dictionary?

Comment: @Amar, please check edit

Comment: @Sayse, for the type of requirement we have, json fits well (for now atleast) since we may add more parameters in future.

Comment: It sounds as though you're looking for a serializer

Comment: `[{i.title: i.specs} for i in Environment.objects.all()]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, this works, thanks

Comment: @Sayse, I never tried serializer. I am going to read this

Comment: @AvinashRaj mentioned the right answer. I guess you can use this one as well. `Environment.objects.values('specs')` and after loop the same.

Comment: If you want a dictionary of a single model object use the inbuild Django method model_to_dict method. Using this you construct list of dictionary representing each object in a queryset. Checkout my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62073213/9384511

Comment: Checkout my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62073213/9384511

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Build a list of dicts with model instance.title as key and the specs as value by iterating over all Environment model instances.

```
[{i.title: i.specs} for i in Environment.objects.all()]
```

Comment: if you want one dict object then it will be: `{i.title: i.specs for i in Environment.objects.all()}`  without adding the comma.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Django model_to_dict

- If you need to convert a `single queryset` into a dictionary, use
  `model_to_dict`.
- If you need to convert `all querysets` into a dictionary use `Model.objects.values()` or [django.core.serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/serialization/#serializing-django-objects)

**using model_to_dict**

```py
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
 
qs = Environment.objects.filter(title=item.title)
 
if qs.exists():
  qs_dict = model_to_dict(qs) # {id:1,'estimate':'some-estimate-data','logic':'some-logic-data'}
  # Do something here with qs_dict
else:
  # qs=None -- do some here when qs is not found
```