# Is there a way to iterate through a single django query object?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

When developing a website i run over a question. I have a query object and i want to iterate through all its` properties like

```
for i in object:
    print(i)
```

Haven`t found anything on Web. Any ideas?

Comment: A query object contains a lot more properties other than the model fields. You can use the `.values` as stated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811556/how-do-i-convert-a-django-queryset-into-list-of-dicts

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot, Nayan! That's exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: I'm posting an answer. Hope you'll accept as it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query object contains a lot more properties other than the model fields. You can use the `.values`.

Here is  how to use this: [How do I convert a Django QuerySet into list of dicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811556/how-do-i-convert-a-django-queryset-into-list-of-dicts)