# Convert Django Queryset to Dict

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset

I'm trying to convert the following queryset into a dictionary that I can then parse via a html template.

```
team | season | type | scope | rank | value
a    | 2018   | reg  | l5    | 5    | 0.118
a    | 2018   | reg  | l10   | 6    | 1.251
b    | 2018   | reg  | l5    | 20   | 0.005
b    | 2018   | reg  | l10   | 15   | 3.058
c    | 2018   | reg  | l5    | 35   | 0.785
```

The issue I'm running into is that I need all rows, and I can't filter down to the 1 instance I need.  I need to be able to place the values in specific spots in my template.

I'd like to turn the query set into a dictionary, at which point I could just reference: team[a].season[2018].type[reg].scope[l5].**rank** and team[a].season[2018].type[reg].scope[l5].**value**.  But I can't figure out how to do so.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far and what went wrong?

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811556/how-do-i-convert-a-django-queryset-into-list-of-dicts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a Django QuerySet into list of dicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811556/how-do-i-convert-a-django-queryset-into-list-of-dicts)

Comment: Thanks!  This solves the first part of my problem.  How would I then parse out a RANK and VALUE field, based on the other parameters in the dictionary?  If I wanted to put one of the values in VALUE field in a HTML, what would the reference template look like?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/62073213/9384511