# Python dict containing decimals into JSON

Tags: python, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python JSON serialize a Decimal object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960516/python-json-serialize-a-decimal-object)

Task: to convert a dict containing a mix of data-types (integer/strint/decimal/...) as values, into JSON array.

I know how to convert a python dict into JSON:

```
D = {key1:val1, key2,val2}
import json
jD = json.dumps(D)
```

I also know that decimal value has to be converted into a string, otherwise python will throw error that 'decimal is not json serializable'.

So I would need to iterate through the dict to look for the data-type.

```
for key in D.keys():
    if type(key) == '<class "decimal.Decimal">': ## this is erroneous. pl. suggest correction
    D[key] = str(D[key])
```

But this programming is involving hand-coding and hard-coding.

If I get a nested dictionary structure, again hard-coding would be required (which is wrong).

Is there any other method/trick to get JSON array from whatever data-type in dict?

Comment: Try *type(key).__name__*

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960516/python-json-serialize-a-decimal-object

Comment: Couldn't you convert datatypes based on the key?

Comment: @JMAx, After using simplejson.dumps with as_decimal=True, I got correct json.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Note that JSON cannot express decimals, only floats and strings. Therefore, you should convert your decimals to strings, like this:

```
keys_for_json = {str(k):v for k,v in keys.items()}
```

Comment: Pl. see my comment to 'Secator's answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Better than Secator's answer

Answer (score 3):

Why not subclass the JSONEncoder?  It's simple and clean:

```
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def _iterencode(self, o, markers=None):

        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):  # isinstance() is better than type(), because it handles inheritance
            return (str(o) for o in [o])

        return super(DecimalEncoder, self)._iterencode(o, markers)
```

Comment: I am looking for a method which would not require any manipulation by hand.  @JMax has suggested simplejson.dumps with as_decimal=True. that works but gives json object enclosed into square brackets [].  Any idea to avoid that?    Thanks.

Comment: @Vineet: your question as you've written here has been closed. If you still have any issue (still enclosed into brackets?), please feel free to ask a new one giving all the necessary information.