# convert a MySQL decimal into an acceptable format to be able to serialize it

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python JSON serialize a Decimal object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960516/python-json-serialize-a-decimal-object)

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    concat(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date), '000') as datetime, 
    SUM(royalty_price) as sales 
FROM 
    sales_raw 
GROUP BY 
    datetime
```

The results look something like:

```
datetime        sales
1337151600000   1045.71 (decimal)
1337238000000   478.04
1337324400000   300.96
1337410800000   289.02
```

From this I get the following error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError at /ajax/graph/
Exception Value: Decimal('1045.71') is not JSON serializable
```

How would I convert the decimal into an acceptable format in mysql to be able to serialize this data?

Comment: I would prefer to do it within mysql if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *must* do it in MySQL, just [`CAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) to a string:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date), '000') AS datetime, 
    CAST(SUM(royalty_price) AS CHAR)    AS sales
FROM 
    sales_raw 
GROUP BY 
    datetime
```

Comment: This would serialize the field into a `JSON` string rather than number (`"1045.71"` rather than `1045.71`). Not sure that what the author wants.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Good point; if the OP wants a floating point number, he can cast to `DOUBLE` instead - although I suppose one should caution about the approximate nature of floating point... since JSON doesn't support fixed-point types, perhaps it should be serialised as two integers (those to the left and right of the decimal point)?  Or else go with a string and perform type conversion within one's application.