# Django how to pass Decimal objects to json

Tags: django, json

I have a query set which contains Decimal objects. I want to pass this data to a json dump along the lines:

```
ql = Product.objects.values_list('length', 'width').get(id=product_id)
data = simplejson.dumps(ql)

TypeError: Decimal('62.20') is not JSON serializable
```

How should I pass these values to json. Of course I could cast the values to string - but I'm guessing this is not a good solution.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Django already includes an encoder than can deal with decimals, as well as datetimes: `django.core.serializers.json.DjangoJSONEncoder`. Just pass that as the `cls` parameter:

```
data = simplejson.dumps(ql, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Comment: I have a problem here. I setted the context to 2 decimals points, but it keeps dumping the whole 8 or 10 decimals points. What I'm missing here?

Comment: Note you will get a `TypeError` error if you are serializing a query set when using `.values` or `.values_list` which returns a `ValuesQuerySet` - force into list for it to work so using above as example it would be: `data = simplejson.dumps(list(ql), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer I found on this question: [Python JSON serialize a Decimal object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960516/python-json-serialize-a-decimal-object)

> How about subclassing json.JSONEncoder?
>
> ```
> class DecimalEncoder(simplejson.JSONEncoder):
>     def _iterencode(self, o, markers=None):
>         if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
>             # wanted a simple yield str(o) in the next line,
>             # but that would mean a yield on the line with super(...),
>             # which wouldn't work (see my comment below), so...
>             return (str(o) for o in [o])
>         return super(DecimalEncoder, self)._iterencode(o, markers)
> ```

---

In your case, you would use it like this:

```
data = simplejson.dumps(ql, cls=DecimalEncoder)
```