# Flask Restless JSON formatting decimal

Tags: python, json, flask-restless

I'm using Flask-Restless 0.17 for an API. The API has several fields that are decimals. I can successfully return decimals by installing simplejson as talked about here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15224186/1753891.

However, when I have a decimal field that is 0, the value is in scientific notation such as `0E-8`. I would like to instead return `0.00000000`.

I'm trying something like this, but an unable to get it to work. The 0 is still returned in scientific notation.

```
class DecimalJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    # Try to format the decimal
    # EDIT: but am now realizing that this doesn't work
    # It was serializing the decimal at all because I had 
    # simplejson installed.
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return format(str(o), '.8f')
        return super(DecimalJSONEncoder, self).default(o)


def init_app(app):
    # .....
    # Use the Flask-Restless postprocessor to format.
    def postprocesor(result, **kw):
        json.dumps(result, cls=DecimalJSONEncoder)
```

How can I force decimals to be `0.00000000` when they are zeros?