# Python to JSON Serialization fails on Decimal

Tags: python, json, decimal

I have a python object which includes some decimals. This is causing the json.dumps() to break.

I got the following solution from SO (e.g. [Python JSON serialize a Decimal object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960516/python-json-serialize-a-decimal-object)) but
the recoomended solution still does not work. Python website - has the exact same answer.

Any suggestions how to make this work?

Thanks. Below is my code. It looks like the dumps() doesn't even go into the specialized encoder.

```
clayton@mserver:~/python> cat test1.py
import json, decimal

class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        def _iterencode(self, o, markers=None):
                print "here we go o is a == ", type(o)
                if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
                        print "woohoo! got a decimal"
                        return (str(o) for o in [o])
                return super(DecimalEncoder, self)._iterencode(o, markers)

z = json.dumps( {'x': decimal.Decimal('5.5')}, cls=DecimalEncoder )
print z
clayton@mserver:~/python> python test1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 11, in <module>
    z = json.dumps( {'x': decimal.Decimal('5.5')}, cls=DecimalEncoder )
  File "/home/clayton/python/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/home/clayton/python/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/home/clayton/python/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 264, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/clayton/python/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 178, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: Decimal('5.5') is not JSON serializable
clayton@mserver:~/python>
```

Comment: Both the second answer on the linked page and [the actual Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) give the correct answer, which is to override `default`. It should be obvious that you shouldn't be overriding `_iterencode`, as the leading underscore implies that that is an internal-only method.

Comment: json doesn't know how to handle `Decimal` so one should extend JSON encoder for Python data structureshttp://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#py-to-json-table

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It is not (no longer) recommended you create a subclass; the `json.dump()` and `json.dumps()` functions take a `default` function:

```
def decimal_default(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
        return float(obj)
    raise TypeError

json.dumps({'x': decimal.Decimal('5.5')}, default=decimal_default)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def decimal_default(obj):
...     if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
...         return float(obj)
...     raise TypeError
... 
>>> json.dumps({'x': decimal.Decimal('5.5')}, default=decimal_default)
'{"x": 5.5}'
```

The code you found only worked on Python 2.6 and overrides a private method that is no longer called in later versions.

Comment: shouldn't your `decimal_default' function return `float(str(obj))` or something like this?

Comment: @oleg: The OP code sample used str. You can return anything you like as long as it is JSON serializable.

Comment: Why not make a subclass? Isn't it far less DRY to pass an argument on every call in every file (and/or error prone to just try and use it wherever you expect a Decimal might be in the input dict)?

Comment: @KyleBaker: you can still subclass `json.JSONEncoder` and implement a [`default()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default) on that subclass.

Comment: casting to `float` will lose accuracy; the duplicate contains approaches that lose none.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: only if producing JSON strings instead of JSON numbers is acceptable and desired.

Comment: @MartijnPieters argh, there is one fix, that works in <~3.5 :/

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Tesdal's fake float approach? Yeah, no, there was never any guarantee that floats would be converted to JSON notation with `repr()`.  :-/

Comment: this solution is fine, but it only handles `decimal.Decimal` unexpected type.

Comment: @FabioCaccamo: which is what the question is *about*. The solution is trivially extended for other unexpected types.

Comment: @FabioCaccamo: your edit on the other hand was entirely inappropriate. You can post your own answer with that solution if you like, but please don't alter mine. Take into account that `str()` conversions are not always the correct approach for serialisation. It is not a fits-all solution.

Answer (score 22):

I can't believe that no one here talked about using simplejson, which supports deserialization of Decimal out of the box.

```
import simplejson
from decimal import Decimal

simplejson.dumps({"salary": Decimal("5000000.00")})
'{"salary": 5000000.00}'

simplejson.dumps({"salary": Decimal("1.1")+Decimal("2.2")-Decimal("3.3")})
'{"salary": 0.0}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the intro to `simplejson`

Comment: It seems simplejson has it's days numbered though, at least as a default part of Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-7

Comment: Are there any downsides using simplejson like this? Otherwise why so many answers go it the hard way?

Answer (score 22):

If you're using Django. There is a great class for Decimal and date fields:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder

To use it:

```
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

json.dumps(value, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```