# Dealing with Decimal to Json in requests library

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to send post data to an api which needs to be in json.  If the requests header doesn't have `Content-type: application-json` the request fails and I get an `HTTPError: 415 Client Error: Unsupported Media Type for url`

However requests only seems to add in this header if I use the inbuilt json parser. Even though the docs seem to suggest the below is equivalent:

```
>>> r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))

>>> r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

Which means that I need to use the built in json parser (or manually add the Content-type header).

However my post data has several Decimal fields (from api converted via `json.loads(response.text, parse_float=decimal.Decimal)` to be saved in a django DecimalField) which when using the inbuilt requests parser gives the error:

```
TypeError: Decimal('1560.35') is not JSON serialisable
```

Is there a way I can use a different json parser with requests (e.g. simplejson which deals with decimals) and have the content-type still specified.

Comment: "the docs seem to suggest": Where?

Comment: Can't you store it as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how to use a different json parser, but you can set the header (and so the content-type).

```py
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'})
# or with a session object
s = requests.Session()
s.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
s.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Comment: thanks this does work (if I manage to not put a typo in the header(!). Together with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957275/python-to-json-serialization-fails-on-decimal

Answer (score 2):

Decimals can be serialized by passing through a custom function.

```
def decimal_default(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
        return str(obj)
    raise TypeError


data = json.dumps(payload, default=decimal_default)

response = requests.post(
    url=url,
    data=data,
    headers={
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just install `simplejson` and `requests` will use it to serialize Decimals:

```
$ pip3 install simplejson
```

This won't raise a `TypeError` anymore:

```
>>> requests.post(url, json={'foo': Decimal('1.23')})
```