# AWS Python SDK: DynamoDB document to JSON

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Actually the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712675/formatting-dynamodb-data-to-normal-json-in-aws-lambda/32737193). but I need solution for Python. 
*Does AWS Python SDK support converting DynamoDB docs to JSON within Python Lambda function?*
In other words I need something like [dynamodb-json](https://pypi.org/project/dynamo-json/) lib within my Lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this :

```
from boto3.dynamodb.types import TypeDeserializer


def _deserialize(raw_data):
    result = {}
    if not raw_data:
        return result

    deserializer = TypeDeserializer()

    for key, val in raw_data.items():
       result[key] = deserializer.deserialize(val)

    return result
```