# Converting aws cli dynamodb json response to regular json

Tags: json, bash, amazon-dynamodb, command-line-interface

I am wondering if there is any way of converting the aws cli response for a dynamodb get-item request from dynamodb json format to regular json format. I am looking for a good way to version an item that is getting updated in a dynamodb table.

I have tried using some node packages (shelljs & dynamodb-converters)

Comment: You might have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712675/formatting-dynamodb-data-to-normal-json-in-aws-lambda

Comment: I think I can use this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```bash
items=$(aws dynamodb scan \
  --table-name "$TABLE_NAME" \
  --query "Items")

echo "$items" | jq "map(with_entries(if .value | type == \"object\" then {key: .key, value: .value[]} else . end)) | sort_by(.${SORT_BY} | tonumber)"
```