# How to convert simple JSON to DynamoDB JSON?

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple JSON and want to convert it to DynamoDB JSON. Is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: Which language AWS SDK are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.7 SDK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean `JsonString` to `Dynamodb Map`, you can use `boto3`.
Here is the example.

```
import boto3
import json

json_string = '{"key1": 1, "key2": "value"}'
json_obj = json.loads(json_string)

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('test-table')

table.put_item(Item={'pk': 'pk-value', 'map': json_obj})
```

If you just want to update the while `Map` attribute, you can use just JSON format the same as `put_item`.

```
json_string = '{"key1": 2, "key2": "value2"}'
json_obj = json.loads(json_string2)
rsp = table.update_item(
    Key={'pk': 'pk-value'},
    AttributeUpdates={'map': {'Value': json_obj2, 'Action': 'PUT'}}
)
```

However, If you want to update only specific nested attribute, you need to use `UpdateExpression`. For example, the below is code to update only `key1` attribute to 'value3'.

```
nested_json_string = '{"nested": "key3"}'
nested_json_obj = json.loads(nested_json_string)

rsp = table.update_item(
    Key={'pk': 'pk-value'},
    UpdateExpression='SET #map.#key1 = :val3',
    ExpressionAttributeNames={'#map':  'map', '#key1': 'key1'},
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':val3': nested_json_obj}
)
```

Comment: It works on `put_item()` but in case of `update_item()` data needs to be in DynamoDB JSON format.  Ex- Simple  format  `{"a":5}` but while update in dynamo db it should be like this - `{"a": {'N' : 5}}`

Comment: If the `value3` is itself a JSON, then this is not working.

Comment: @Vikash Yadav Did you even try? it works for me. I change the example with string value to jsonObj value.

Comment: Thanks but I came to know that there is this module in python `dynamodb_json` , that can convert json to DynamoDB json `from dynamodb_json import json_util as json  dynamodb_json = json.dumps(json_)`. In above case I was directly passing the JSON string, sorry my bad.

Comment: @SangminKim how can we achieve the same in java ?
I have normal json and i want to convert it in DynamoDB JSON. On using gson, i am able to achieve it to some extent. But the datatype fields are in small letters - "s" instead of "S" as for string in dynamodb json

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I came across it and the accepted answer didn't help me (it seems to suggest that you can feed `boto3` with plain JSON, but it didn't work for me) and the library mentioned in the comments didn't help me either.

What *did* work for me was using the serializer/deserializer from [boto3.dynamodb.types](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/types.html), basically as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47664534) answer on a very similar topic.

```
from boto3.dynamodb.types import TypeSerializer, TypeDeserializer
import json

serializer = TypeSerializer()
deserializer = TypeDeserializer()


# for building a DynamoDB JSON from a Python object
def serialize(item):
    serialized_item = serializer.serialize(vars(item) if hasattr(item, '__dict__') else item)

    return item if 'M' not in serialized_item else serialized_item['M']


# for building a plain JSON from a DynamoDB JSON
def deserialize(dynamodb_json_string):
    return deserializer.deserialize({'M': dynamodb_json_string})


class MyItem:
    def __init__(self, some_string_value=None, some_numeric_value=None):
        self.my_key = some_string_value
        self.my_other_key = some_numeric_value

    def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda x: x.__dict__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_classy_item = MyItem("my_string_value", 5)
    my_string_item = json.loads('{"my_key": "my_string_value", "my_other_key" : 5}')

    print(serialize(my_classy_item))
    print(serialize(my_string_item))
```