# query on dynamodb through lambda using pk and sk returns undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a lambda function that makes a call to the dynamodb table using pk and sk. For some reason I am getting the return data as undefined. Upon checking the cloudwatch logs I see the below error messages. What could be the typo I am doing here?

**2021-10-01T00:15:03.104Z  cdd7201f-0c95-4283-9257-c07324998896    INFO    BOL Data: undefined**

**2021-10-01T00:15:03.124Z  cdd7201f-0c95-4283-9257-c07324998896    INFO    BOL Error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'PK' of undefined
at getUserById (/var/task/getUserById.js:16:27)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)**

Here is the lambda code the error is referring to -

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

async function getUserById(userId) {
    console.log('USERID:',userId);
    const params = {
        TableName:"Bol",
        KeyConditionExpression: 'PK = :hashKey and SK = :sortKey',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':hashKey': userId,
            ':sortKey': 'USER'
        }
    };
    try {
        const { Item } = await docClient.query(params).promise();
        console.log('BOL Data:',Item);
        return { id: Item.PK, name: Item.Data.displayName };
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("BOL Error: ", err);
    }
 }
 
 module.exports = getUserById;
```

Below is the data I am supposed to receive on lambda -
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the way you are Initialization  the `Item`

you can try using the below methods to get the objects

```html
 try {
        const Item  = await docClient.query(params).promise();
        Item.Items.forEach(function(item) {
            let buffer=item.Data+" -- "+item.PK;
           console.log("buffer ",buffer)
        });
        
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("BOL Error: ", err);
    }
```

There's are multiple ways you can get the favourable response refer below:

[Making Requests with the Document Client](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-the-amazon-dynamodb-document-client-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript/)

[Formatting DynamoDB data to normal JSON in AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712675/formatting-dynamodb-data-to-normal-json-in-aws-lambda)

Comment: Thanks Ruben, your answer got me thinking in the right direction