# Formatting DynamoDB data to normal JSON in AWS Lambda in Rust

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-rust

How can I convert a DynamoDB view JSON to a normal JSON in Rust?

For example, I want to convert:

```json
{
 "id": {
  "N": "123"
 },
 "name": {
  "S": "some name"
 }
}
```

to this:

```json
{
 "id": 123,
 "name": "some name"
}
```

I've found this question [Formatting DynamoDB data to normal JSON in AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712675/formatting-dynamodb-data-to-normal-json-in-aws-lambda) with several answers for Node.js or Python.

Is there a converter like `unmarshall` ([JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Converter.html)) or `TypeDeserializer.deserialize` ([Python](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/types.html)) for Rust in the [aws-sdk-rust](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-rust)?

Comment: You can try using the from_attribute_map method of the serde_dynamodb::from_dynamodb trait. `let item: Item = from_dynamodb(serde_json::from_str(dynamodb_json).unwrap()).unwrap();`

Comment: Therefore, I'd need to use `rusoto_dynamodb`, but I'd like to use `aws-sdk-dynamodb`. So this won't work out of the box.