# Display trailing zeros in a decimal number in python without returning a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

**I need to display trailing zeros in a decimal number**. I have consider using [python format()](https://pyformat.info/) but it **returns a string** and when I **convert it to float or decimal** the **trailing zero disappear**s.

I have also tried using [python decimal](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/decimal.html) but it returns a **Decimal instance** on variable assignment.
For example:

```
>>> x = decimal.Decimal(format(15.2, '.2f'))
>>> print x
15.20
>>> x
Decimal('15.20')
```

**Python version: 2.7**

**I need to display 15.2 as 15.20 (not as '15.20' << string type)**

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What is wrong with it returning it as a string?  You certainly can display that and the trailing zeros will appear.

Comment: @wallyk Its a part of my django app where the api returns some json data and my front end is expecting float or decimal. If i could directly obtain the expected decimal value then it could help me reduce some operations performed at front end.

Comment: You cannot do this. Floating point number representation does not include trailing zeros.

Comment: @DYZ Is there any way i could get value from decimal instance code shown above? as shown by >>> print x

Comment: Sure: `float(x)`. But whatever value you get, is going to be a floating-point number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `float` subclass that behaves this way:

```
class RoundFloat(float):
    def __new__(cls, value=0, places=2):
        return float.__new__(cls, value)
    def __init__(self, value=0, places=2):
        self.places = str(places)
    def __str__(self): 
        return ("%." + self.places + "f") % self
    __repr__ = __str__
```

Usage:

```
pi = RoundFloat(3.1415927, places=4)
print pi         # 3.1416
```

It may be convenient to leave off the `__repr__` so you can easily get the full value if you need it using `repr(x)`.

Comment: I thought you wanted decimals, not float. I'd look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3148376/1904113