# Json decimal serializable error while doing json.dumps

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to write a lambda function to write a list to s3 object. Below is my function.

```
print result,type(result)  
a =s3.put_object(Bucket='mybucket',key='data.json',Body=json.dumps(result))
```

error

> [{u'Vote': Decimal('5'), u'Name': u'Akbar'}, {u'Vote': Decimal('4'), u'Name': >u'Amar'}, {u'Vote': Decimal('2'), u'Name': u'Antony'}, {u'Vote': Decimal('15'), >u'Name': u'Yunoth'}] '
> type 'list'
>
> TypeError: Decimal('5') is not JSON serializable

Comment: Try, this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960516/python-json-serialize-a-decimal-object

Comment: simplejson is not an option in aws-lambda

Comment: Whay are you using decimals for what is obviously a plain integer ???

Comment: Result is a list from dynamodb table scan.