# Retreiving Floating Point values from MySQL dataabase to Python Flask

Tags: python, mysql, json, flask

my problem is that I would like to retrieve a result set from the database with columns having different data types, it works fine with all data types except floating points.

I get this error" TypeError: Object of type 'Decimal' is not JSON serializable "

I read some solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/a/3885198/6079156 but I don't know how to use them to solve my problem. sample code:

```
from flask import render_template


def employee():

    # salary's data type is decimal(8,2) in the database
    cursor.execute("SELECT ID, dateofbirth, type, salary FROM employee")

    result= cursor.fetchall()

    return render_template('Employee.html', result=result)
```

Comment: Nothing in this code is serializing to JSON, so you need to show the code that is actually doing that as well as the full traceback.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I had a session variable but for the sake of simplicity I removed it from here, little did I know that it caused the problem.