# TypeError: Decimal('0.00') is not JSON serializable on Graphene mutation object response

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

This application is built on top of `Flask` where which I'm currently working on a user reset password functionality. This is defined as a mutation for client post request.

The client will give its password for verification then sends him an email and the mutation will return a `UserField` scalar type.

Moreover I'm using `marshmallow` library for serialising data.

**models.py**

```
class User(db.model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    name = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    email = db.Column(db.Unicode, unique=True, nullable=False)
    credit_account = db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=12, scale=2), default=0)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(Schema):
    name = fields.String()
    email = fields.String()
    credit_account = fields.Decimal() # Decimal types here!!!
```

> NOTE: There is a Decimal field on the UserSerializer which is the root problem on graphql

---

Below code is the implementation of `GraphQL` Mutation. We use the `graphene` library for python.

**fields.py**

```
class UserField(Scalar):

    @staticmethod
    def serialize(user):
        json = UserSerializer()
        return json.dump(user).data

    @staticmethod
    def parse_literal(node):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def parse_value(value):
        pass
```

**mutations.py**

```
class ResetUserPassword(graphene.Mutation):
    user = graphene.Field(UserField)

    def mutate(self, info, password):
        user = get_user(password=password)
        send_email(user=user,email=user.email, template='reset_password_template') 
        return ResetUserPassword(user=user)
```

**Usage:**

```
{
    "query": "mutation { resetPassword(password: \"foobar\") { user }}"
}
```

Now here I got this TypeError raised on the console:

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: Decimal('0.00') is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: I believe it is a json encoder problem..Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960516/python-json-serialize-a-decimal-object)

Comment: @drec4s Before posting here I found that but I still don't have any idea how to implement it, I also read about install simplejson but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: moreover I cannot seem to find where to use `DecimalEncoder` on marshmallow `Schema`