# How to convert decimal numbers stored as JSON into decimal with Django?

Tags: python, django

I store Decimal numbers in JSONField with Django in order to have flexible amount of digits but then I'm unable to use them. This is how my model looks like.

```
from decimal import Decimal
# from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
import simplejson

class Order(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    size = JSONField(null=True)
```

Following the recommendation from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3148376/3423825 and store the value like this:

```
import simplejson as json
self.size = json.dumps(Decimal('1'), use_decimal=True)
```

Now when I try to convert it to decimal I get an error.

```
size = Decimal(self.size)

Object of type 'Decimal' is not JSON serializable
```

I must say I'm a bit lost because `type(self.size)` returns `<class string>` so I should be able to convert it to `Decimal`, or am'I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: Why not use `DecimalField` instead? Your database will not be able to do any arithmetic operations on JSON fields, for one.

Comment: @AKX `DecimalField` is for a fixed-precision decimal number but my numbers have various precision of decimal number.

Comment: If you have an upper limit on the precision/number of digits you want to store, you can just set that for the field.

Comment: Yes but I need to store `Decimal('1')` as `1` and `Decimal('1.1')` as `1.1` in the same field. With `DecimalField` and `decimal_places=1`, `Decimal('1')` will be stored as `1.0` not `1`

Comment: If it's absolutely crucial to store e.g. `Decimal('42.000000')` verbatim, you might just want to subclass `CharField` or `TextField` to a `DecimalAsStringField`...