# TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, decimal, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

### `TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable`

---

While I am running in `postman api` i get the above error because `sales_qty` is decimal , I dont know how to parse `decimal` in a `for` loop and return it as json

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify

import decimal,json

result= [('V_M_001', 'KITE', 'Napkin', 1, 2, 12, 0, Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0')), 
        ('V_M_001', 'KITE', 'Napkin', 2, 4, 34, 5, Decimal('1'), Decimal('4'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('0'))]
        
def fun():

   for i in result:
        data_all.append({
                            "machine_name":i.machine_name,
                            "location":i.location, 
                            "item_name":i.item_name,
                            "row_no":i.row_no,
                            "require_minimum_stk_qty":i.require_minimum_stk_qty,
                            "capacity":i.capacity,
                            "stock_qty":i.stock_qty,
                            "sales_qty":i.sales_qty,
                            "available_qty":i.available_qty,
                            "sales_day_qty":i.sales_day_qty,
                            "sales_week_qty":i.sales_week_qty
        
        })
        
    return jsonify(data_all)

fun()
```

Output:
`TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python JSON serialize a Decimal object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960516/python-json-serialize-a-decimal-object)

Comment: no could you suggest different solution

Comment: There are two JSON numeric types, `int` and `float`. No complex, no `Decimal`. So if you want to use JSON to represent your data you have little choice but to decide which of the two available types you want. Or, if  preserving the precision of `decimal.Decimal` is important, you can pass the data as a string and leave the conversion up to the receiving process.

Answer (score 6):

Use json.dump with cls argument, I believe that when ever the json module dont know how to convert, it will call the default function.

````
import json
import decimal

class Encoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal): return float(obj)

json.dumps( ... , cls = Encoder)

```python
````

Answer (score 3):

```
import decimal

from flask import current_app as app
from flask import Jsonify
from flask.json import JSONEncoder

class JsonEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
            return float(obj)
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

@app.route('/test_jsonify')
def test_jsonify():
    data = {
        'float': 7.5,
        'decimal': decimal.Decimal(7.5)
    }

    app.json_encoder = JsonEncoder
    return jsonify(data)
```

(found here [Flask Jsonify Custom JsonEncoder | Lua Software Code](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/flask/flask-jsonify-custom-jsonencoder/))

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It’s a totally work code with the Flask. For more experience you can use link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `json.dumps()` with default encoder `str()`.

```py
json.dumps( dict_obj_with_decimal , default = str)
```

Comment: this is a quick solution if you don't bother about the data *type* but most of the time, json as data exchange require and/or preserve data type.