# Convert queryset to dictionary with native data types?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a `Stocks` model and I'm using `values` as such:

```
Stock.objects.values("ticker", "stock", "exchange__exchange_code", "earnings_yield", "roic")
```

The `earnings_yield` and `roic` values are stored in my db as decimal, and Django returns their type as such:

```
{'ticker': 'AAPL', 'stock': 'Apple', 'exchange__exchange_code': 'NASDAQ', 'earnings_yield': Decimal('0.0000'), 'roic': Decimal('0.0000')}
```

How can I convert the `'roic': Decimal('0.0000')` and get back `'roic': 0.0000` instead?

Comment: Why is that a problem ?

Comment: For JSON purposes

Comment: So maybe this answer can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960649/8439435