# Deserialize json string containing arbitrary-precision float numbers, and serialize it back

Tags: python, json

Python has no built-in arbitrary-precision floats. Here is an example:

```
>>> float(4.4257052820783003)
4.4257052820783
```

So it doesn't matter what you use, you can't have a float object with arbitrary precision.

Let's say I have a *JSON string* (`json_string = '{"abc": 4.4257052820783003}'`) containing an arbitrary-precision float. If I load that string, Python will cut the number:

```
>>> dct = json.loads(json_string)
>>> dct
{'abc': 4.4257052820783}
```

I managed to avoid this loss of info by using `decimal.Decimal`:

```
>>> dct = json.loads(json_string, parse_float=Decimal)
>>> dct
{'abc': Decimal('4.4257052820783003')}
```

Now, I would like to serialize this `dct` object to the original JSON formatted string. `json.dumps(dct)` clearly does not work (because objects of type Decimal are not JSON serializable). I tried to subclass `json.JSONEncoder` and redefine its `default` method:

```
class MyJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, Decimal):
            return str(o)
        return super().default(o)
```

But this is clearly creating a string instead of a number:

```
>>> MyJSONEncoder().encode(dct)
'{"abc": "4.4257052820783003"}'
```

How can I serialize a `Decimal` object to a JSON number (real) instead of a JSON string? In other words, I want the encode operation to return the original `json_string` string. Ideally without using external packages (but solutions using external packages are still welcome).

This question is of course very related but I can't find an answer there: [Python JSON serialize a Decimal object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960516/python-json-serialize-a-decimal-object).

Comment: do you need to store it as a float inside the dict? can you convert it to a float at runtime?

Comment: As you said, it's impossible to get a float with the required precision.  You'll need to somehow trick the JSON encoder into outputting the string without the quotes.

Comment: What I mean is just use strings all the way until you need it then convert just that string to a float

Comment: Looking at the code, I don't think you can do what you want without substantially rewriting chunks of the JSON module itself. Take a look at [the code for `json.encoder`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/json/encoder.py) and look at where `_floatstr` is called; you would need to update all of these points to also handle `Decimal` objects.

Comment: Can you show me how you use the data

Comment: @anarchy it doesn't matter when or how you convert to float, a float simply doesn't have enough precision.  You won't get the same number you put in.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for pointing me to the `json.encoder` code. Looking at it, one could actually redefine the `_make_iterencode` function and subclass `JSONEncoder`. However this would require much code just to change a couple of lines (i.e., almost copy the whole module code just to change a couple of lines). It doesn't look like the module functionalities are easily extendible.

Answer (score 9):

Use [simplejson.dumps](https://simplejson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=use_decimal#simplejson.dumps):

> If ***use_decimal*** is `true` (default: `True`) then `decimal.Decimal` will be natively serialized to JSON with full precision.

```
import json
import simplejson
from decimal import Decimal

dct = json.loads('{"abc": 4.4257052820783003}', parse_float=Decimal)

print(dct)
print(simplejson.dumps(dct, use_decimal=True))
print(simplejson.dumps(dct)) # Also works, if Decimal in the dct.
```

Output:

```
{'abc': Decimal('4.4257052820783003')}
{"abc": 4.4257052820783003}
{"abc": 4.4257052820783003}
```

Comment: I wonder why the regular `json` module didn't get updated to handle this?  It looks like you can also use `simplejson.loads()` and dump the old module altogether.

Comment: Thanks +1. This is indeed useful. As I said, I would prefer to use only the standard library, but I will accept your solution if nobody else come up with something else!

Answer (score 4):

The following only uses the default library. It works by effectively "overriding" json.encoder._make_iterencode (see discussion below, after this example)...

```
from decimal import Decimal
import json

def _our_make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,
        _key_separator, _item_separator, _sort_keys, _skipkeys, _one_shot,
        ## HACK: hand-optimized bytecode; turn globals into locals
        ValueError=ValueError,
        dict=dict,
        float=float,
        id=id,
        int=int,
        isinstance=isinstance,
        list=list,
        str=str,
        tuple=tuple,
        _intstr=int.__repr__,
    ):

    if _indent is not None and not isinstance(_indent, str):
        _indent = ' ' * _indent

    def _iterencode_list(lst, _current_indent_level):

        if not lst:
            yield '[]'
            return
        if markers is not None:
            markerid = id(lst)
            if markerid in markers:
                raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
            markers[markerid] = lst
        buf = '['
        if _indent is not None:
            _current_indent_level += 1
            newline_indent = '\n' + _indent * _current_indent_level
            separator = _item_separator + newline_indent
            buf += newline_indent
        else:
            newline_indent = None
            separator = _item_separator
        first = True
        for value in lst:
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                buf = separator
            if isinstance(value, str):
                yield buf + _encoder(value)
            elif value is None:
                yield buf + 'null'
            elif value is True:
                yield buf + 'true'
            elif value is False:
                yield buf + 'false'
            elif isinstance(value, int):
                # Subclasses of int/float may override __repr__, but we still
                # want to encode them as integers/floats in JSON. One example
                # within the standard library is IntEnum.
                yield buf + _intstr(value)
            elif isinstance(value, float):
                # see comment above for int
                yield buf + _floatstr(value)
            else:
                yield buf
                if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
                    chunks = _iterencode_list(value, _current_indent_level)
                elif isinstance(value, dict):
                    chunks = _iterencode_dict(value, _current_indent_level)
                else:
                    chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
                yield from chunks
        if newline_indent is not None:
            _current_indent_level -= 1
            yield '\n' + _indent * _current_indent_level
        yield ']'
        if markers is not None:
            del markers[markerid]

    def _iterencode_dict(dct, _current_indent_level):
        if not dct:
            yield '{}'
            return
        if markers is not None:
            markerid = id(dct)
            if markerid in markers:
                raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
            markers[markerid] = dct
        yield '{'
        if _indent is not None:
            _current_indent_level += 1
            newline_indent = '\n' + _indent * _current_indent_level
            item_separator = _item_separator + newline_indent
            yield newline_indent
        else:
            newline_indent = None
            item_separator = _item_separator
        first = True
        if _sort_keys:
            items = sorted(dct.items())
        else:
            items = dct.items()
        for key, value in items:
            if isinstance(key, str):
                pass
            # JavaScript is weakly typed for these, so it makes sense to
            # also allow them.  Many encoders seem to do something like this.
            elif isinstance(key, float):
                # see comment for int/float in _make_iterencode
                key = _floatstr(key)
            elif key is True:
                key = 'true'
            elif key is False:
                key = 'false'
            elif key is None:
                key = 'null'
            elif isinstance(key, int):
                # see comment for int/float in _make_iterencode
                key = _intstr(key)
            elif _skipkeys:
                continue
            else:
                raise TypeError(f'keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, '
                                f'not {key.__class__.__name__}')
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                yield item_separator
            yield _encoder(key)
            yield _key_separator
            if isinstance(value, str):
                yield _encoder(value)
            elif value is None:
                yield 'null'
            elif value is True:
                yield 'true'
            elif value is False:
                yield 'false'
            elif isinstance(value, int):
                # see comment for int/float in _make_iterencode
                yield _intstr(value)
            elif isinstance(value, float):
                # see comment for int/float in _make_iterencode
                yield _floatstr(value)
            else:
                if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
                    chunks = _iterencode_list(value, _current_indent_level)
                elif isinstance(value, dict):
                    chunks = _iterencode_dict(value, _current_indent_level)
                else:
                    chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
                yield from chunks
        if newline_indent is not None:
            _current_indent_level -= 1
            yield '\n' + _indent * _current_indent_level
        yield '}'
        if markers is not None:
            del markers[markerid]

    def _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level):
        if isinstance(o, str):
            yield _encoder(o)
        elif isinstance(o, Decimal):
            yield str(o) # unquoted string.
        elif o is None:
            yield 'null'
        elif o is True:
            yield 'true'
        elif o is False:
            yield 'false'
        elif isinstance(o, int):
            # see comment for int/float in _make_iterencode
            yield _intstr(o)
        elif isinstance(o, float):
            # see comment for int/float in _make_iterencode
            yield _floatstr(o)
        elif isinstance(o, (list, tuple)):
            yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)
        elif isinstance(o, dict):
            yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
        else:
            if markers is not None:
                markerid = id(o)
                if markerid in markers:
                    raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
                markers[markerid] = o
            o = _default(o)
            yield from _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
            if markers is not None:
                del markers[markerid]
    return _iterencode

class BigDecimalJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
 
    def iterencode(self, o, _one_shot=False):
        """Encode the given object and yield each string
        representation as available.

        For example::

            for chunk in JSONEncoder().iterencode(bigobject):
                mysocket.write(chunk)

        """
        if self.check_circular:
            markers = {}
        else:
            markers = None
        if self.ensure_ascii:
            _encoder = json.encoder.encode_basestring_ascii
        else:
            _encoder = json.encoder.encode_basestring

        def floatstr(o, allow_nan=self.allow_nan,
                _repr=float.__repr__, _inf=json.encoder.INFINITY, _neginf=-json.encoder.INFINITY):
            # Check for specials.  Note that this type of test is processor
            # and/or platform-specific, so do tests which don't depend on the
            # internals.

            if o != o:
                text = 'NaN'
            elif o == _inf:
                text = 'Infinity'
            elif o == _neginf:
                text = '-Infinity'
            else:
                return _repr(o)

            if not allow_nan:
                raise ValueError(
                    "Out of range float values are not JSON compliant: " +
                    repr(o))

            return text

        _one_shot = False
        if (_one_shot and json.encoder.c_make_encoder is not None
                and self.indent is None):
            _iterencode = json.encoder.c_make_encoder(
                markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent,
                self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
                self.skipkeys, self.allow_nan)
        else:
            _iterencode = _our_make_iterencode(
                markers, self.default, _encoder, self.indent, floatstr,
                self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
                self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
        return _iterencode(o, 0)

json_string = '{"abc": 4.4257052820783003}'
dct = json.loads(json_string, parse_float=Decimal)
print(f"decoded={dct}")
print(f"encoded={json.dumps(dct, cls=BigDecimalJSONEncoder, indent=4)}")
```

**Example output:**

```
decoded={'abc': Decimal('4.4257052820783003')}
encoded={
    "abc": 4.4257052820783003
}
```

**Discussion:**

The main problem is that json.encoder does not provide an acceptable way to override json.JSONEncoder to a return string (i.e., from json.JSONEncoder.default) that is to be accepted as raw ready-to-go JSON string.

For example, consider the following *pseudo* ideal override...

```
class IdealDecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o) -> Union[Any, tuple[str, bool]]:
        if isinstance(o, Decimal):
            return str(o), False # return object (str) and False which means "do not quote".
        return super().default(o)
```

The above allows `default` to return the object (as it does today) or a tuple, where the second value is False if no further encoding should be performed (i.e., a string that should not be quoted). As we know, this is not supported.

The next question would then be, what lies between the call to `default` and `iterencode`... unfortunately, it's the `json.encoder._make_iterencode` function which essentially produces a generator that relies on several "private" functions. If this were a class, or if the functions were broken out and accessible, you could perform a more terse override.

In my working example above, I essentially copy/pasted `_make_iterencode` simply to add the following single case to the private `_iterencode` generator...

```
    ...
    elif isinstance(o, Decimal):
        yield str(o) # unquoted string.
    ...
```

This obviously works because it returns an unquoted string. The 'str' case always uses _encoder which assumes a string requiring quotes for JSON, where the override bypasses that for Decimal.

Not a great solution but the only reasonable one I can see which uses only the built-in library which does not require parsing/decoding/modifying encoded JSON during the encoding process.

It has not been tested beyond the @Riccardo Bucco (OP)'s example.

Assuming no unforeseen back-compat issue, it seems it would be a relatively easy to modify Python to include this for Decimal.

Without something built in, I'm wondering if it's best, for now, to use one of the other JSON libraries supporting Decimal as others have discussed.

Comment: This was exactly the only solution I came up with. +1, thanks for reporting it. I agree it's not a beautiful solution (because it requires you to copy and paste most of the json module), but I don't think there are other ways to do it

Answer (score 2):

This code does not use anything that is not part of the standard library, but does require defining a custom-tailored `dumps` function.

The idea is to serialize a `Decimal` value such as `Decimal('1.0000000000000000001')` to 10000000000000000001E-19. This is a two step process:

1. First encode `Decimal('1.0000000000000000001')` to its string representation, i.e. "Decimal('1.0000000000000000001')".
2. Then scan the entire resulting serialized string to replace strings such "Decimal('1.0000000000000000001)" with the floating point value  10000000000000000001E-19, **which loses no precision when expressed this way**.

```py
import json
from decimal import Decimal
import re

class MyJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, Decimal):
            return repr(o)
        return super().default(o)

split_rex = re.compile(r'''("Decimal\('[^']+'\))"''')
match_rex = re.compile(r"'([^']+)'")

def dumps(o):
    json_string = json.dumps(o, cls=MyJSONEncoder)
    arr = re.split(split_rex, json_string)
    # Process each Decimal
    for idx in range(1,len(arr),2):
        string_rep = re.search(match_rex, arr[idx])[1]
        # Look for decimal point
        index = string_rep.find('.')
        if index == -1: # No decimal point
            arr[idx] = string_rep + 'E-0'
        else:
            l = len(string_rep)
            # number of places after decimal point:
            precision = l - index - 1
            # Remove decimal point
            string_rep = string_rep[:index] + string_rep[index+1:] + f'E-{precision}'
            arr[idx] = string_rep
    return ''.join(arr)

dicts = [
    {'a': "some value", 'b': Decimal('1234'), "c": 1234},
    {'a': "some value", 'b': Decimal('1.0000000000000000001'), "c": 1234}
]

for d in dicts:
    json_string = dumps(d)
    print(f'dictionary = {d}\nserialized = {repr(json_string)}\nun-serialized = {json.loads(json_string, parse_float=Decimal)}\n')
```

Prints:

```None
dictionary = {'a': 'some value', 'b': Decimal('1234'), 'c': 1234}
serialized = '{"a": "some value", "b": 1234E-0, "c": 1234}'
un-serialized = {'a': 'some value', 'b': Decimal('1234'), 'c': 1234}

dictionary = {'a': 'some value', 'b': Decimal('1.0000000000000000001'), 'c': 1234}
serialized = '{"a": "some value", "b": 10000000000000000001E-19, "c": 1234}'
un-serialized = {'a': 'some value', 'b': Decimal('1.0000000000000000001'), 'c': 1234}
```

**A Second Simpler Solution**

```py
import json
from decimal import Decimal

class MyJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, Decimal):
            # To eliminate (almost) all possibility of mistaken identity:
            return 'MyJSONEncoder Decimal: ' + str(o)
        return super().default(o)

def dumps(o):
    arr = list(MyJSONEncoder().iterencode(o))
    for idx, json_string in enumerate(arr):
        if json_string.startswith('"MyJSONEncoder Decimal: '):
            string_rep = json_string[24:-1]
            # Look for decimal point
            index = string_rep.find('.')
            if index == -1: # No decimal point
                arr[idx] = string_rep + 'E-0'
            else:
                l = len(string_rep)
                # number of places after decimal point:
                precision = l - index - 1
                # Remove decimal point
                string_rep = string_rep[:index] + string_rep[index+1:] + f'E-{precision}'
                arr[idx] = string_rep
    return ''.join(arr)

dicts = [
    {'a': "some value", 'b': Decimal('1234'), "c": 1234},
    {'a': "some value", 'b': Decimal('1.0000000000000000001'), "c": 1234}
]

for d in dicts:
    json_string = dumps(d)
    print(f'dictionary = {d}\nserialized = {repr(json_string)}\nun-serialized = {json.loads(json_string, parse_float=Decimal)}\n')
```

Prints:

```None
dictionary = {'a': 'some value', 'b': Decimal('1234'), 'c': 1234}
serialized = '{"a": "some value", "b": 1234E-0, "c": 1234}'
un-serialized = {'a': 'some value', 'b': Decimal('1234'), 'c': 1234}

dictionary = {'a': 'some value', 'b': Decimal('1.0000000000000000001'), 'c': 1234}
serialized = '{"a": "some value", "b": 10000000000000000001E-19, "c": 1234}'
un-serialized = {'a': 'some value', 'b': Decimal('1.0000000000000000001'), 'c': 1234}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution!!  +1 Of course this does not work in an (extreme) edge case in which the Decimal representation is part of a string. Is there a reason why you decided to use the syntax with the exponent instead of the normal one?

Comment: I have posted a second simpler solution where it is even more unlikely that an arbitrary string could be mistaken for a Decimal value before the entire serialized string is post-processed. I cannot encode `Decimal('1234')` as `1234.` because that cannot be decoded without raising an exception. I would have to encode it as `1234.0` but then that would be decoded as `Decimal('1234.0')`, which is not the same precision as the original value. `1234E-0` is both a float value and it can be decoded to the correct precision.