# Inner Classes: How can I get the outer-class object at construction time?

Tags: python

Consider the following Python (runs in 2.x or 3.x):

```
class Outer(object):
  pass

  class Inner(object):
    def __init__(self):
      print("Inner.self", self)

o = Outer()
i = o.Inner()
```

I want to get my hands on `o` while inside `Inner.__init__()`.  But:

- I don't want `o` to be an explicit parameter to `Inner`.
- I want `O.Inner` and `o.Inner` to be a class object, not something weird like a closure.

Can you suggest how I might achieve this?

Right now my best idea is to use thread local storage.  In my use case, whenever I construct an `o.Inner()`, I'm already inside a method on `o` somewhere, and it wouldn't be a big deal to add

```
threading.local()["my o object"] = o
```

to my code.

This gives you an idea of the level of depravity I'm willing to consider.

Comment: This is one of those cases where we have to ask: "What is it that you're trying to accomplish? Because there's probably a better way to do it." In Java, you can't put two (public) classes in the same file unless one of them is inside the other. In Python, there is no such requirement, so there is probably a way to do what you want without using inner classes at all.

Comment: Linking in [Access outer class from inner class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2024566/674039)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Python 2.6, a class decorator that's also a custom descriptor matches the specs you give:

```
class InnerClassDescriptor(object):
  def __init__(self, cls):
    self.cls = cls
  def __get__(self, instance, outerclass):
    class Wrapper(self.cls):
      outer = instance
    Wrapper.__name__ = self.cls.__name__
    return Wrapper

class Outer(object):
  @InnerClassDescriptor
  class Inner(object):
    def __init__(self):
      print self.outer

o = Outer()
i = o.Inner()
print 'Outer is a', type(Outer)
print 'Inner is a', type(o.Inner)
```

This emits:

```
<__main__.Outer object at 0x82f90>
Outer is a <type 'type'>
Inner is a <type 'type'>
```

just to confirm that

> o.Inner [[is]] a class object, not
>   something weird like a closure

as per your peculiar specs.  Of course it needs to be a *different* class each time for reentrancy -- even in a single-threaded world, the following:

```
o1 = Outer()
o2 = Outer()
i1 = o1.Inner
i2 = o2.Inner
print i1(), i2(), i1(), i2()
```

should work cleanly, and stashing o1 vs o2 anywhere else than in the classes returned by `o1.Inner` vs `o2.Inner` (e.g., in TLS) would mean horrible results for this use.

But then you *didn't* specify "`o.Inner` has to be **exactly** the same class object for *every* possible `o` that's an instance of `Outer`", so this code fully meets the specs you *did* give;-).

Comment: Marvelous!  Now I must meditate whether I can live with o1.Inner != o2.Inner != Outer.Inner.  Of course, bound methods != unbound methods, so it only makes sense that bound child classes != unbound child classes.

Comment: As written your approach returns a new class every time o.Inner is referenced, so "assert o.Inner == o.Inner" would fail.  Caching the Wrapper class in the instance, like setattr(instance, "__cache__" + self.cls.__name__), then preferring the cached version where available, solves that at least.

Comment: Another tweak: if "instance" is None, then the __get__ should return self.cls.  Without this isinstance(i, Outer.Inner) returns False.

Comment: Finally, @LarryHastings has posted a recipe http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577070-bound-inner-classes/

Comment: @xmedeko fine solution, but `Inner` has wrong signature.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a metaclass to implement a [__get__](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__get__#object.__get__) descriptor that binds the inner class to the outer one.  And since you seem to be interested in only binding to a class, consider modifying the inner class in-place, unlike a function which is wrapped into a method.

```
>>> class Outer(object):
    class Inner(object):
        class __metaclass__(type):
            def __get__(self, instance, owner):
                self.owner = owner
                return self


>>> Outer.Inner is Outer().Inner
True
>>> Outer.Inner.owner is Outer
True
```

If you'd rather wrap the inner class via a subclass then replace the __get__ body with:

```
return type(self.__name__, (self,), {'owner': owner})
```

Comment: Let me play with it a little more, but I think this may serve my purposes better than Alex Martelli's admittedly-mind-meltingly-cool answer.  If so, I'll switch my checkmark.  Thanks!

(And to all of you who said "it can't be done"--phooey!)

Comment: I'm giving you a check, as you did solve the problem as stated, with a creative solution that showed me something new.  But I can't use this approach.  The unfixable problem is that it cannot be multithread-safe.  However as that was not a stated requirement I can't fault you for not handling it.

Comment: Sorry, new to Stack Overflow, I thought you *could* give multiple checks.  I'll definitely give you an upvote, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Can't be done. But with a bit of redesign:

```
class Outer(object):
  pass

  class _Inner(object):
    def __init__(self, outobj):
      self.outobj = outobj

  def Inner(self):
    return self._Inner(self)

o = Outer()
i = o.Inner()

print o, i.outobj
```

Comment: that’s cool. you simply specify what the inner class needs and you generate it via function from the outer object.

Comment: Actually, I think can be done (unless you are describing something else to what I think). See my answer for a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

You should redesign your code not to use inner classes and to explicitly pass the instance of Outer to Inner when you make it, or not to require it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't (in any portable, reliable or efficient way.) Nested classes have no relation to the nesting class. They have no added value, either. Instead of using nested classes, use containment of instances -- define `Outer` and `Inner` separately, and create an instance of `Inner` in `Outer.__init__`, possibly passing `Outer` or the `Outer` instance if you need it. You can make `Inner` a class attribute of `Outer` if you insist, but it will have no special access to `Outer`.

Comment: @Thomas, so which one of the three characteristics you think my answer is missing -- seems pretty portable, reliable, _and_ efficient to me (also pretty elegant, if I say so myself;-).  The "special access" comes through Inner being a _custom descriptor_ class (which wraps the original Inner class object via decorator syntax -- that's where the 2.6 requirement comes, as it needs to be a _class_ decorator of course) -- so that, whenever `o.Inner` is accessed, `o.Inner.__get__` comes into play (and gets `o` as an argument).

Comment: To be honest I didn't think of using a class decorator. It still seems  like a nasty hack for no decent purpose. As for which of the three it lacks, obviously portability (it only works in Python 2.6 and later :) -- although I would point out that with your solution the inner class can't itself be a descriptor. And subsequent code in the class block can't use the inner class directly, which is presumably part of the reason it's an inner class in the first place. All in all I still stand by my answer that you shouldn't be creating interdependent classes like this; the complexity isn't worth it.

Answer (score 0):

See [Access outer class from inner class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024566/access-outer-class-from-inner-class-in-python/35118717#35118717) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35118717/3787376)

for a simple reliable answer I made that only uses variables, attributes, functions and classes - no special code.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for python 3 (I'm using 3.7, don't know for earlier versions or 2.x)

```py
from functools import wraps
from inspect import signature as _signature

class _Bound:
    '''type of bound methodsand classes'''
    def __init__(self, callable):
        self._callable = callable
    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        'called when instance.callable or Class.callable'
        if instance is None: # called on class, not instance
            return self._callable

        @wraps(self._callable)
        def retf(*a, **k):
            try: 
                return self._callable(instance, *a, **k)
            except: # information if failed
                # user did `self.callable(*args, **kwargs)` and failed
                print(f'failed call of {self._callable}')
                print(f'self:   {instance}')
                print(f'args:   {a}')
                print(f'kwargs: {k}')
                raise 
        # additional wrap to expell first argument
        sig = _signature(retf)
        retf.__signature__ = sig.replace(parameters=tuple(sig.parameters.values())[1:])

        return retf
    def __call__(self, *a, **k):
        'Class.__dict__['BoundMethod'](instance, *a, **k) (c(), 55, 8, key=9)'
        return self._callable(*a, **k)
    pass

class UnBound:
    "similar to static, only doesn't change attribute at all (except for builtin-like method making)"
    def __init__(self, callable):
        self.callable = callable
    pass
class class_(classmethod):
    pass
class static(staticmethod):
    pass

class NestedType(type):
    '''meta to support nested classes (and other callables)
    meta to outer class'''
    @staticmethod
    def bind(dict):
        for name, attr in dict.items():
            if callable(attr) and not isinstance(attr, (class_, static)): #functions, classes, ...
                dict[name] = _Bound(attr)
            elif isinstance(attr, UnBound):
                dict[name] = attr.callable
    def __new__(meta, object_or_name, bases, dict):
        NestedType.bind(dict)
        return type.__new__(meta, object_or_name, bases, dict)

class NestedBase(metaclass=NestedType):
    pass
```

**example**

```py
class Outer(<note0>):
    class Inner:
        def __init__(self, self_): # I prefer self_ above outer
```

note0: here can come `NestedBase` or `metaclass=NestedType` (and beware of meta mismatch error)

**need to know**
`Outer.Inner` return class `module.Outer.Inner`
`Outer().Inner` returns bound method
`Outer.__dict__['Inner']` returns bound object `_Bound...`

**note1**
imports are not that important, they only change pop-up when using IDE (VScode python extension doesn't recognize it, so it displays it wrongly, but IDLE does)

**classes explained**
`_Bound` should not be used

used as a decorator:
`UnBound` will make old-style binding
`class_` same as classmethod
`static` same as staticmethod

`NestedType` metaclass to the outer class
`NestedBase` base to the outer class
only one needed per outer class

**note2**
inner class that has no decorator `UnBound` needs to have init that receives `<Outer object>` as 2nd argument
otherwise will write (see `_Bound.__get__.retf.except`) and throw `TypeError: Inner(?) takes ? arguments`

**meta mismatch**
to see meta mismatch write `class M(type): pass`,  `class A(NestedBase): pass`, `class B(metaclass=M): pass`, `class C(A, B): pass`
solution: create submeta of both metas and, if , call `NestedType.bind(dict)` (as in `NestedType.__new__`)
note3: overriding `__new__` or NestedMeta not 1st in subclassing order (`class NewMeta(NotNestedMeta, NestedMeta)` ( here `NestedMeta` is non-strict submeta of `NestedType`)

Answer (score 0):

without changing or even invokign `__init__` methods we can use a kind of Inner class factory that simply adds the parent or outer reference

```
class Outer(object):
   pass

   class _Inner(object):
      def __init__(self):
         print("Inner.self", self)
         print (self.outer)

   def InnerFactory (self):
      class Inner(self._Inner):
         outer = self
      return Inner

o = Outer()

Iclass = o.InnerFactory()
i = Iclass()
# or directly
i = o.InnerFactory()()
```

this approach is of most interest in cases where we cannot change or have no control over the construction or `__init__` method

to illustrate the last situation, on creating an HTTPServer with

```
srv = HTTPServer(addresAndPort, MyHTTPRequestHandler)
```

we pass a class for the request handler, it will be initialized when the server receive a request, so we have no control over its `__init__` invokation, but with the technique described we can add watever we want to the handler class, for example

```
def RichHTTPRequestHandler ():
    class Rich(MyHTTPRequestHandler):
        parent = whatever
        otherStuff = etc
    return Rich

srv = HTTPServer(hostAddresAndPort, RichHTTPRequestHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Alex Martelli's brilliant answer, I came up with another solution to this problem using a descriptor on a metaclass:

```
class InnerMeta(type):
    def __get__(cls, instance, owner):
        cls.outer = owner
        return cls

class Outer:
    class Inner(metaclass=InnerMeta):
        """Inner doc"""
        def __init__(self):
            print(self.outer)


o1 = Outer()
o2 = Outer()
i1 = o1.Inner()
i2 = o2.Inner()

assert type(i1) is type(i2)
print(type(i1).__name__)
print(type(i1).__doc__)
```

output:

```
<class '__main__.Outer'>
<class '__main__.Outer'>
Inner
Inner doc
```

The class definition of Inner is equivalent to:

```
Inner = InnerMeta("Inner", (), {})
```

hence, InnerMeta should implement the descriptor protocol.