# Set dictionary key to attribute of class instance

Tags: python, class, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary which stores objects of a class `foo`. Class `foo` has an attribute `Name`. For every instance, I want the `Name` attribute to be the key to the instance in the dictionary. All instances of the class will be defined inside the dictionary.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Name = None  #self.Name should equal "self"

foo_dict = {
'foo1' = foo()
}

#(foo.Name should equal 'foo1')
```

How can I set the `Name` attribute to be the key to the instance in the dictionary?

Comment if specifications are needed.

Comment: How do you access the ```Name``` attribute?

Comment: In the initialization

Comment: Can you access an instance variable before it is instantiated?  Have you made any attempts to solve this?

Comment: Well I do not believe so. As far as attempts, I know that I need to use `self.Name = foo_dict[???]`. But since the instantiation is happening after the dictionary key/ dictionary entry is created, can't I somehow assign the key to `self.Name`?

Comment: What would the `.Name` be if you do: `f = foo(); foo_dict = {'foo1': f, 'foo2': f,}` ?

Comment: I'm not certain, but that case will not appear in my program. All instances of the class will be defined inside the dictionary.

Comment: `foo.Name` is a class attribute (which is shared by all instances of `class foo` -- so your question makes little sense.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need a reference to the instance to do what you want.  If you build the dictionary with a comprehension, you can create instance references and use them.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, n = None):
        self.name = n

d = {f.name:f for f in (Foo(n) for n in 'abcd')}

>>> d
{'a': <__main__.Foo object at 0x03DF9710>, 'c': <__main__.Foo object at 0x03E01250>, 'b': <__main__.Foo object at 0x03DF9A50>, 'd': <__main__.Foo object at 0x03E01290>}
>>> 
>>> d = {f.name:f for f in (Foo(n) for n in [1])}
>>> d
{1: <__main__.Foo object at 0x03E01B50>}
>>> foo_dict = {}
>>> foo_dict.update(d)
>>> foo_dict
{1: <__main__.Foo object at 0x03E01B50>}
>>>
```

I stumbled upon [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2278595/2823755) the other day.  Using that class decorator/descriptor, you could create a class factory that produces `Foo` objects and keeps track of the current object and a counter for the next object.

```
class InnerClassDescriptor(object):
    '''allows access to the outer class and its attributes

    decorator/descriptor
    an instance of a nested inner class can access the outer class and its attributes
    '''
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self.cls = cls
    def __get__(self, instance, outerclass):
        class Wrapper(self.cls):
              outer = instance
        Wrapper.__name__ = self.cls.__name__
        return Wrapper

class FooFactory(object):
    next_foo = 0
    this_foo = None
    @InnerClassDescriptor
    class Foo(object):
        def __init__(self):
            # print 'Foo,__init__, next_foo = ', self.outer.next_foo
            self.name = 'Foo' + str(self.outer.next_foo)
            self.outer.next_foo += 1
            self.outer.this_foo = self
```

Usage:

```
ff = FooFactory()
d = {ff.this_foo.name:ff.Foo()}
for k, v in d.items():
    print k, v.name

>>> 
Foo0 Foo0
>>>
```

This relies on the dictionary item value being evaluated before the key - which seems to be the case for Python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

I can't possibly stress enough how BAD this is... Please, please, use this only for educational purposes. It's crumbly, unreliable... **BAD** If you change anything in your code, it'll stop working. It is dirty. It is possibly non portable... OMG... I think a few kittens were killed when I hit <kbd>Post Your Answer</kbd>

```
import inspect
import re

class Foo(object):
        def __init__(self):
            r = re.compile(
                r"\W+['\"](?P<name>\w+)['\"]\W+%s\W+"
                % self.__class__.__name__
            )
            caller_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
            code_context = inspect.getframeinfo(caller_frame).code_context
            match = r.match(''.join(code_context))
            if match:
                self.name = match.groupdict()['name']
                print "Assigned name: %s" % self.name
            else:
                raise Exception("This wasn't called as it was supposed to")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo_dict = {
        'foo1': Foo(),
        'foo2': Foo(),
    }
```

But it does what you seem to be asking:

```
borrajax@borrajax:/tmp$ python ./test.py 
Assigned name: foo1
Assigned name: foo2
```

Now, what I would do is:

### Option 1:

Pass the name in the initialization.

Possibly the simplest, most maintainable and that leaves the code in a much clearer state (important if someone else reads your code)

```
class Foo(object):
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
            print "Assigned name: %s" % self.name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo_dict = {
        'foo1': Foo('foo1'),
        'foo2': Foo('foo2'),
    }
```

### Option 2:

Create your own `dict` class and overwrite the [__setitem__](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) method (see also [Subclassing Python dictionary to override __setitem__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060972/subclassing-python-dictionary-to-override-setitem) and [How to "perfectly" override a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387691/python-how-to-perfectly-override-a-dict)):

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

class MyDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if not isinstance(val, Foo):
            raise TypeError("My dict only accepts %s" % Foo)
        val.name = key
        print "Assigned name: %s" % val.name
        return super(MyDict, self).__setitem__(key, val)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo_dict = MyDict()
    foo_dict['foo1'] = Foo()
    foo_dict['foo2'] = Foo()
    foo_dict['foo3'] = 1
```

Prints:

```
borrajax@borrajax:/tmp$ python ./test.py 
Assigned name: foo1
Assigned name: foo2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./stack64.py", line 17, in <module>
    foo_dict['foo3'] = 1
  File "./stack64.py", line 8, in __setitem__
    raise TypeError("My dict only accepts %s" % Foo)
TypeError: My dict only accepts <class '__main__.Foo'>
```

This has the disadvantage of *magically* adding attributes (the `.name`) to the instances of `Foo` when assigned to the dictionary, which can cause name conflicts (if your `Foo` class already had a `.name`, this method would change its value). In general, I'd stay away of methods that magically add attributes to instances in the middle of the execution.

### Option 3:

Use @[Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3555845/daniel)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27333581/289011) to this question. Clean and understandable for someone else reading your code.

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way round:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name

foo1 = Foo('foo1')
foo_dict = {
    foo1.name: foo1
}
```

Comment: I said, "All instances of the class will be defined inside the dictionary". This means the instance will be instantiated inside the dictionary and be assigned a dictionary key. `foo_dict = {'foo1': Foo()}`