# nested class can't inherit from outer class

Tags: python, oop

My problem is quite similar to this one:
[Access outer class from inner class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024566/access-outer-class-from-inner-class-in-python)

I am using tkinter and need a 2|3-level tree and plan to make my code structure similar to the Ui => nested class.

```
class Item():
    ...
class BasicItem():
    ...

class Transports(Item):
    class Bikes(Item):
        class Tears(BasicItem):
class Feelings(Item):
    class Tears(BasicItem):
```

Python complains because the classes can't be reached from the nested classes. What am I doing wrong?
According to the above link, nested are no the way to go. Am I to understand that I should flatten my code and use a *TransportsBikesTears* class name?
Thank you.

edit: A minimal example works. I will try to rewrite from a working file.
edit2: This example nested in a mother-class fail.

Comment: The provided code works for me

Comment: You should expand your example to show how you want to use these nested classes.  Do you want to access fields of `Transports` in `Bikes`?  If so, then you probably want to use inheritance, not nesting.

Comment: Using nested classes provides no real benefit and makes the code more complex. I suggest removing the nesting.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I removed the nested part.

Answer (score 0):

I learned that classes are nor supported in Python but works "sometimes" as an artifact. I can't find the link but since people keeps using it, they are considering removing this artifact.

My mistake came from trying this in a function and that comforted me with this practice.
One you put my example above in a mother-class, it won't work and the nested class won't be able to inherit from *Item*.

Lesson learned. No more nested classes in Python.