# python how to make inner class to be type of outer class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I have nested classes because they are tightly related.

Now i want to have the following type of code

```
class one(Some-other-type):
    ...
    // More functions here

    class two(one):
       // Some more functions here.
```

The Inner class "two" type should be "one" but if i put that i get an error.
The other way is to not make it nested like below

```
class one(Some-other-type):
    ...
    // More functions here

class two(one):
    // Some more functions here.
```

But then i dont want class "two" to be accessible when the module is imported.
I dont really care about the functions offered by "one" but it needs to be under it for clarity of code.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access outer class from inner class in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024566/access-outer-class-from-inner-class-in-python)

Comment: "But then i dont want class "two" to be accessible when the module is imported." Python doesn't bother with access modifiers like `private`. Just put  an underscore in front of `class _two` to indicate it's private. Because in the other case, the calss is always accessible anyway through `one.two`.

Comment: @Evert yea i guess thats the way to go

Comment: Also, you could use `__all__ = ['one']` see [Importing a Package](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)

Comment: @BryceGuinta that only affects `from somemodule import *` type imports, AFAIK.

Comment: If you are using nested classes in Python, you are almost certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The only way I'm seeing a leading underscore different from `__all__` is that IPython autocomplete doesn't pick up leading underscore attributes. However you can directly access the 'hidden' attribute either way. The leading underscore is more explicit in that the attribute is not intended to be used outside of the module however.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is it wrong in design perspective?

Comment: @Anup Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to the class while it is being constructed. However you can refer to a class inside its own method since the method body isn't evaluated until after the class in constructed.

```
class one(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_two():
        class two(one):
           pass
        return two()
    def f(self):
        print("I am %s" % type(self).__name__)
```

`two` inherits `f` from `one`

```
>>> obj = one.get_two()
>>> obj.f()
"I am two"
```

Comment: A possibly significant downside to this is that each instance you get from `get_two` will be an instance of a different `two` class. That is, the classes will have the same name (and same methods, etc.), but they won't be the same class. `type(one.get_two()) != type(one.get_two())`

Comment: @Blckknght You're right. get_two() could return the class and you could just instantiate `two` objects from only that class type if that mattered.