# How to properly access instance variables in one inner-class from another inner-class?

Tags: ruby, inner-classes

I'm creating a game of tic-tac-toe. I am new to ruby, and have defined a class `Game`, with two inner-classes `Player` and `GameBoard`. Within `Game` I define two instance-variables `player1` and `player2`. I am trying to access both `player1` and `player2` inside of the method `GameBoard.update_gameboard` like so

```
def update_gameboard(player)
      move = if player == 1
               @player1.moves[@player1.turn]
             else
               @player2.moves[@player2.turn]
             end
.
.
.
```

And I get the error:

```
/Users/Jacob/Development/RubyDev/RubymineProjects/TicTacToe/tictactoe.rb:85:in `update_gameboard': undefined method `moves' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/Jacob/Development/RubyDev/RubymineProjects/TicTacToe/tictactoe.rb:44:in `play'
    from /Users/Jacob/Development/RubyDev/RubymineProjects/TicTacTOe/main.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

`moves` is *not* a method, it's an array. (`play` is a method in `Game` which calls `update_gameboard`)

***How do I access the instance-variables of an outer-class (`Game`) from an inner class (e.g. `GameBoard`)?***

```
class Game
  attr_accessor :winner, :player1, :player2, :gameboard

  def initialize(player1_name, player2_name)
    @player1 = Player.new(player1_name, 'X')
    @player2 = Player.new(player2_name, 'O')
    @gameboard = GameBoard.new
  end
.
.
.
  class GameBoard
    attr_accessor :current_gameboard
    attr_reader :gameboard_move_map

    def initialize
          # initialize irrelevant GameBoard variables
    end

    def update_gameboard(player)
      move = if player == 1
               @player1.moves[@player1.turn]
             else
               @player2.moves[@player2.turn]
             end
      #then some more stuff that uses @player1 and @player2
    end
.
.
.
  end
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access outer class from inner class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024566/access-outer-class-from-inner-class-in-python)

Comment: @IshaanJavali I saw that question. With respect to this situation, it did not help me.

Comment: That could possibly be because I'm not educated enough in OOP to understand how to apply those instances to my work in ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really important concept here. "Inner class" does not do what you think it is. There is absolutely no relationship or special behavior between the two classes, other than namespacing. Basically, just treat the inner class like it is defined totally separately, because that's how it behaves.

One thing you can do, though, is pass the `GameBoard` constructor a reference to the `Game` instance, so you can access the instance variables:

(note that i am only showing the parts relevant for the answer, and am ommitting the other bits of your code for the sake of being succinct):

```
class GameBoard
  attr_reader :game
  def initialize(game)
    @game = game
  end
end

class Game
  def initialize(player1_name, player2_name)
    @player1 = Player.new(player1_name, 'X')
    @player2 = Player.new(player2_name, 'O')

    # Note I pass the Game instance as self here:
    @gameboard = GameBoard.new(self)
  end
end
```

Then inside the `GameBoard` instance methods, you can do something like this:

```
game.player1.moves[game.player1.turn]
```

`game` here is the method generated by attr_reader (referring to the `@game` instance variable set in initialize).

Comment: Awesome. Really great answer.