# How to represent file structure as python objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

I'm trying to find a way to represent a file structure as python objects so I can easily get a specific path without having to type out the string everything. This works for my case because I have a static file structure (Not changing).

I thought I could represent directories as class's and files in the directory as class/static variables.

I want to be able to navigate through python objects so that it returns the path I want i.e:

```
print(FileStructure.details.file1) # root\details\file1.txt
print(FileStructure.details) # root\details
```

What I get instead from the code below is:

```
print("{0}".format(FileStructure())) # root
print("{0}".format(FileStructure)) # <class '__main__.FileStructure'>
print("{0}".format(FileStructure.details)) # <class '__main__.FileStructure.details'>
print("{0}".format(FileStructure.details.file1)) # details\file1.txt
```

The code I have so far is...

```
import os 

class FileStructure(object): # Root directory
    root = "root"

    class details(object): # details directory
        root = "details"
        file1 = os.path.join(root, "file1.txt") # File in details directory
        file2 = os.path.join(root, "file2.txt") # File in details directory

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.root}"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.root}"
```

I don't want to have to instantiate the class to have this work. My question is:

1. How can I call the class object and have it return a string instead
   of the < class ....> text
2. How can I have nested classes use their parent classes?

Comment: Why not instantiate the class? Is it acceptable if the class is instantiated silently, so you never see the instance?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I don't  want the user to instantiate it everytime explicitly like `usethisclass = TheClass()`. What do you mean instantiate it silently?

Comment: Side-note: [There is no way for the nested class to use its parent class implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2024566/364696), so your design is already not really going to work.

Comment: If you put `@object.__new__` on the line immediately before `class FileStructure...`, it will silently create an instance of `FileStructure` and assign it to the name `FileStructure` (so the class itself will no longer have a global name, only the instance will exist with that name).

Comment: @ShadowRanger So it seems like I have the wrong approach. At least I learnt something new with the object decorator. Thanks!

Comment: You have noticed that you'll write more using the solution you're asking than writing directly, the str representation of the path, right?

Comment: Just use `pathlib` don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: @ShadowRanger isn't FileObject = FileObject() a much more explicit way to do that?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Absolutely. But you have to type it like, three times, and that's *terrible*. [DRY FTW!!!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(computer_programming)) ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with: you probably don't actually want this. Python3's [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pathlib.html) API seems nicer than this and is already in wide support.

```
root = pathlib.Path('root')
file1 = root / 'details' / 'file1'  # a Path object at that address

if file1.is_file():
    file1.unlink()
else:
    try:
        file1.rmdir()
    except OSError as e:
        # directory isn't empty
```

But if you're dead set on this for some reason, you'll need to override `__getattr__` to create a new `FileStructure` object and keep track of parents and children.

```
class FileStructure(object):
    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        self.__name = name
        self.__children = []
        self.__parent = parent

    @property
    def parent(self):
        return self.__parent

    @property
    def children(self):
        return self.__children

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # retrieve the existing child if it exists
        fs = next((fs for fs in self.__children if fs.name == attr), None)
        if fs is not None:
            return fs

        # otherwise create a new one, append it to children, and return it.
        new_name = attr
        new_parent = self
        fs = self.__class__(new_name, new_parent)
        self.__children.append(fs)
        return fs
```

Then use it with:

```
root = FileStructure("root", None)
file1 = root.details.file1
```

You can add a `__str__` and `__repr__` to help your representations. You could even include a `path` property

```
# inside FileStructure
@property
def path(self):
    names = [self.name]
    cur = self
    while cur.parent is not None:
        cur = cur.parent
        names.append(cur.name)
    return '/' + '/'.join(names[::-1])

def __str__(self):
    return self.path
```

Comment: fun lil tidbit: \_\_getattr\_\_ is only called if the requested attribute isn't found in the usual way, so `if attr in ['parent', ...]` isn't necessary.  ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278077/difference-between-getattr-vs-getattribute

Comment: @DeeBee oh interesting! Thanks for that -- I had planned on testing that but ran out of time before I had to submit an answer or get back to work. I was pleasantly surprised that my code even ran when I dropped it into an interpreter later :)

Answer (score 1):

Up front: This is a *bad* solution, but it meets your requirements with minimal changes. Basically, you need instances for `__str__` to work, so this cheats using the decorator syntax to change your class declaration into a singleton instantiation of the declared class. Since it's [impossible to reference outer classes from nested classes implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2024566/364696), the reference is performed explicitly. And to reuse `__str__`, `file1` and `file2` were made into `@property`s so they can use the `str` form of the `details` instance to build themselves.

```
@object.__new__
class FileStructure(object): # Root directory
    root = "root"

    @object.__new__
    class details(object): # details directory
        root = "details"
        @property
        def file1(self):
            return os.path.join(str(self), 'file1')
        @property
        def file2(self):
            return os.path.join(str(self), 'file2')

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{os.path.join(FileStructure.root, self.root)}"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.root}"
```

Again: While this does produce your desired behavior, this is still a *bad* solution. I strongly suspect you've got [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040) here, but this answers the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

There exists such class in [HTMLgen](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Eamitp/Python/code/HTMLgen/html/HTMLutil-Directory.html):

```
import HTMLutil

class Directory(UserList)
  def __cmp__(self, item)
  def __init__(self, name='root', data=None)
  def add_object(self, pathlist, object)
  def ls(self, pad='')
  def tree(self)

  # Methods inherited by Directory from UserList
  def __add__(self, list)
  def __delitem__(self, i)
  def __delslice__(self, i, j)
  def __getitem__(self, i)
  def __getslice__(self, i, j)
  def __len__(self)
  def __mul__(self, n)
  def __mul__(self, n)
  def __radd__(self, list)
  def __repr__(self)
  def __setitem__(self, i, item)
  def __setslice__(self, i, j, list)
  def append(self, item)
  def count(self, item)
  def index(self, item)
  def insert(self, i, item)
  def remove(self, item)
  def reverse(self)
  def sort(self, *args)
```

Unfortunately, this package is very old. When I tried to understand code for [Directory.__cmp__](https://github.com/dbohdan/HTMLgen/blob/master/HTMLutil.py), I failed. It is supposed to compare directory structures, but it calls a function *cmp* for that, and where that function comes from is unclear to me (*types* in Python 3 have no such function). I'm not sure it works any longer.

I thought about creating such package myself to test directory hierarchies (I created a file synchronization program). However, as suggested in answers above, *pathlib* might be a better approach, as well as [dircmp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html#the-dircmp-class) from *filecmp* and [rmtree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) from *shutil*.

The downside of these standard modules is that they are low-level, so if someone creates a library to deal with all these tasks in one place, that would be great.