# python - how to reference Class declared inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a Class from a third party lib I am using.

```
def funcA(base):
    class ClassA(base):
        def __init__(self, obj):
        ....
```

I have an instance of ClassA `a`

```
type(a)

# prints <class 'path.to.module.funcA.<locals>.ClassA'>
```

How can I check if a variable is an instance of ClassA?
I am not sure how to reference ClassA since it is under a function....

```
import module
isinstance(a, module.funcA.ClassA?) <--- how to reference ClassA?
```

Comment: Why do you need to do such a test? Define interfaces,  adopt duck typing.  BTW, if that class is local to the function,  either it's bad OO design or you're trying to tweak things

Comment: No such check is possible, at least not in any usual way.  There's no way to reference the class directly, and in fact a brand new class object is created every time the function is called.  All of the classes have the same name, and behave identically - but an instance of one class version fails the `isinstance` check with any other version.  The best you could do would be something like `type(a).__name__ == "ClassA"`.

Comment: You could return an ClassA object, but that’s the best I could get from what I found. Somehow related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024566/how-to-access-outer-class-from-an-inner-class

Comment: Python *doesn't have class declarations* (or any declarations, really). A class definition statement is essentially syntactic sugar for a call to the `type` constructor, assigning the resulting class object to the `ClassA` local variable. Like any local variable, it isn't accessible outside the function

Comment: Now, yuo *can* recover the class if you have an instance of it, `ClassA = type(a)` and now you can reference `ClassA` in that scope

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to change `funcA` itself because it's not in your own code, then a neat way to test for instances is to give it a superclass and test for the superclass. Replace `funcA` with a wrapped version, which calls the original `funcA` with a class that extends both `base` and your own `ClassABase`:

```py
import functools

class ClassABase:
    pass

def funcAwrapper(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(base):
        class WrappedBase(base, ClassABase):
            pass
        return f(WrappedBase)
    return wrapper

funcA = funcAwrapper(funcA)
```

Now all of the instances of `ClassA` created by `funcA` will also be instances of your own `ClassABase`, so you can test `isinstance(obj, ClassABase)`.