# How to access a class constant inside class Meta?

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    CONSTANT = "value"
    ...
    class Meta:
        # I want to Access CONSTANT here
```

I know a simple solution of hardcoding the "value" inside class Meta, but is there a way to access the outer class CONSTANT. I tried CONSTANT and MyClass.CONSTANT inside class Meta, but these two ways did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access outer class from an inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024566/how-to-access-outer-class-from-an-inner-class)

Comment: `MyClass.Meta.stuff`?

Answer (score 0):

```py
class MyClass:
    CONST = 'val from MyClass'
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.meta = self.Meta()
    
    class Meta:
        def __init__(self):
            self.value = MyClass.CONST
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_class = MyClass()
    print(my_class.meta.value)


# something like this
```