# How to Access Outer class variables in Inner Class (Python)?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

How to access the variables of the outer class in the Inner Class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access outer class from an inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024566/how-to-access-outer-class-from-an-inner-class)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,Name,rollNumber):
        self.Name=Name
        self.rollNumber=rollNumber
        self.lap=self.Laptop()

    def Show(self):
        print(self.Name)
        print(self.lap.show())
        
    class Laptop:

        def __init__(self):
            self.brand = "Mac"
            self.cpu = "i9"
            self.ram = 16

        def show(self):
            return self.brand

        @staticmethod
        def Show():
            return s1.Name

s1=Student("Teja",2)
print(s1.Name,s1.rollNumber)


s1.Show()
print(s1.lap.brand)

system=s1.lap
print(system.brand)
print(system.cpu)
print(system.show())

print(system.Show())
```

Comment: The original poster wants to know how to access the outer class variables from *within* the inner class. What you've posted is how to access the *inner* class variables via the outer class.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.