# Serialize both inner and outer class arguments

Tags: python, python-class

I'm not quite sure I'm using the right wording in my researches -- if that's the case, please let me know, I may have missed obvious answers just because of that -- but I'd like to serialize (i.e. convert to a dictionary or JSON structure) both the main (outer) and inner class arguments of a class.

Here's an example:

```py
class Outer(object):
    
    def __init__(self, idx, array1, array2):
        self.idx = idx
        # flatten individual values:
        ## unpack first array
        self.prop_a = array1[0]
        self.prop_b = array1[1]
        self.prop_c = array1[2]
        ## unpack second array
        self.prop_d = array2[0]
        self.prop_e = array2[1]
        self.prop_f = array2[2]

        # Nest elements to fit a wanted JSON schema
        class inner1(object):
            def __init__(self, outer):
                self.prop_a = outer.prop_a
                self.prop_b = outer.prop_b
                self.prop_c = outer.prop_c

        class inner2(object):
            def __init__(self, outer):
                self.prop_d = outer.prop_d
                self.prop_e = outer.prop_e
                self.prop_f = outer.prop_f
        
        self.inner_first = inner1(self)
        self.inner_second = inner2(self)
   
    def serialize(self):
        return vars(self)
```

Now I can call both:

```py
import numpy as np

obj = Outer(10, np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6]))
obj.prop_a # returns 1, or
obj.inner_first.prop_1 # also returns 1
```

But when I try to serialize it, it prints:

```py
vars(obj) # prints:

{'idx': 10,
 'prop_a': 1,
 'prop_b': 2,
 'prop_c': 3,
 'prop_d': 4,
 'prop_e': 5,
 'prop_f': 6,
 'inner_first': <__main__.Outer.__init__.<locals>.inner1 at 0x7f231a4fe3b0>,
 'inner_second': <__main__.Outer.__init__.<locals>.inner2 at 0x7f231a4febc0>}
```

where I want it to print:

```py
vars(obj) # prints:

{'idx': 10,
 'prop_a': 1,
 'prop_b': 2,
 'prop_c': 3,
 'prop_d': 4,
 'prop_e': 5,
 'prop_f': 6,
 'inner_first': {'prop_a': 1, 'prop_b': 2, 'prop_c': 3},
 'inner_second': {'prop_d': 4, 'prop_e': 5, 'prop_f': 6}}
```

with the `'inner_first'` key being the actual results of `vars(obj.inner_first)`, and same thing for the `'inner_second'` key.

Ideally I'd like to call the `serialize()` method to convert my object to the desired output: `obj.serialize()`

I feel I'm close to the results but I can simply not see where I must go to solve this task.

At the really end, I wish I could simply:

```py
obj = Outer(10, np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6]))
obj.serialze()

{
  'inner_first': {
    'prop_a': 1,
    'prop_b': 2,
    'prop_c': 3
  },
  'inner_second': {
    'prop_d': 4,
    'prop_e': 5,
    'prop_f': 6
  }
}
```

in order to basically fit a given JSON structure that I have.

Info: this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024566/how-to-access-outer-class-from-an-inner-class) helped me to build the inner classes.

Also note that this question only embeds two "layers" or "levels" of the final structure, but I may have more than 2.

Comment: "But when I try to serialize it" ... `vars` is not serialization. Why do you think it is?

Comment: Indeed. But I was always using `vars()` on objects to dump them as `dict`. And as all my objects, up to now, were only having a 1-level structure, it was perfectly equivalent to a serialization to me.