# How do I access an attribute from a parent class in Python?

Tags: python

This doesn't work:

```
class parent:
    a=1
    class child:
        b=a+1
```

nor does

```
class parent:
    a=1
    class child:
        b=parent.a+1
```

nor does

```
class parent:
    a=1
    class child:
        b=self.a+1
```

nor does

```
class parent:
    a=1
    class child:
        b=super().a+1
```

What do I do? I've heard that Stack Overflow can be quite toxic, but I'm hoping it's not true. Please understand that I'm new here.

Comment: That's not the proper way of expressing inheritance in Python. The child class must have the same indentation as the parent class, and you express the inheritance through parenthesis (i.e. `class child(parent):`.

Comment: You should read through https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html.

Comment: There is no parent-child class relationship in the code you posted. You are *nesting* a class definition inside another, but that is not a parent-child relationship.  Indeed, in Python, that doesn't have any particular significance, other than as a way of organizing namespaces (unlike in say, Java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not reflect properly in your code. As per [inheritance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-python/) of classes you inherit from a parent class. But in your code you are trying to call outerclass from an inner class.

One solution might be like this (According to your question):

```py
class Parent:
    a = 1

class Child(Parent):
    b = Parent.a + 1


parent = Parent()
child = Child()

print(parent.a) # output: 1
print(child.b) # output: 2
```

But if you really want to access outer class from inner class then you can visit
[How to access outer class from an inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2024566/13497846) (according to your code)

Comment: What's the difference between inheritance and call outer class from inner class?

Comment: I've mentioned that in my answer. You can get an idea of inheritance from [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-python/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-python/) and about the inner-outter class visit [https://stackoverflow.com/q/2024566/13497846](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2024566/13497846)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)
        self.b = self.a +1
        
child_class = Child()
print(child_class.b)
```

Maybe something like this.

Comment: `Parent.__init__(self)` -> `super().__init__()`

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to create a child class is like this:

```
class parent():
    a = 1

# child class inherits attributes from parent like this
class child(parent):
    b = 2

# so when you instantiate an object of class child...
child_object = child()

# ... you can access its parent's attributes directly like this:
print(child_object.a + child_object.b)
```

If you want to access the parent's attribute inside a method, you can do like this:

```
class child(parent):
    b = 2

    def sum_with_parent(self):
        # you can either use self.a to access the parent attribute,
        # since 'class child(parent):' made the proper inheritance
        sum1 = self.b + self.a

        # or you can use the super().a, but bear in mind that 'super()'
        # is actually creating a fresh instance of parent
        # that is, it's calling __init__ from parent
        sum2 = self.b + super().a

        return sum1 == sum2 #this will return true
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems like you don’t quite understand what inheritance is. Here is a quick “deep” dive.

## What is inheritance in OOP?

Inheritance is a fundamental concept in object oriented programming. It is when you provide a base or super class for another class. The super class usually contains functionality that will apply, or be useful, to any instance of the classes deriving from it. It prevents you from having to reimplement things.

### Inheritance in Python

In Python, a class deriving from another class automatically is able to access methods and attributes defined in super class, through the `super()` function:

```py
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print("bar")
        
class Bar(Foo):
    def bar(self):
        super().bar()
        
b = Bar()
b.bar() # bar
```

Even if we use the convention for showing some method or attribute is private, which is prefixing with an underscore, Python doesn’t enforce this and we can still access it:

```py
class Foo:
    def _bar(self):
        print("bar")
        
class Bar(Foo):
    def bar(self):
        super()._bar()
        
b = Bar()
b.bar() # bar
```

### Inheritance in Other OO Languages

In other object oriented languages like C#, there are access modifiers. Marking a method with `public` means it has no restrictions to what can access it. It can be accessed by:

- All code in the assembly it was defined in
- All code in any assemblies referencing the assembly where it was defined

But, C# gives us the option to multiple other access modifiers, including `private`. Marking something as `prívate` means it can only be accessed by the code in the same class, or struct, it was defined in:

```cs
class Foo 
{
    private string _x = "Foo";
}

static void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();

    Console.WriteLine(foo._x); // compile time error
}
```

But, restricted members can be indirectly accessed through a public API:

```cs
class Foo 
{
    private string _x = "Foo";

    public string AccessPrivate()
    {
        return _x;
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();

    Console.WriteLine(foo.AccessPrivate());
}
```

## Python’s `super()` function

> *mCoding* on YouTube has a great video explaining [how `super()` works](https://youtu.be/X1PQ7zzltz4)

Simply, `super()` will give you access to methods in a superclass, from subclasses that inherit from it. Calling it actually returns a *temporary object* of the superclass, letting you access its methods and attributes.

The official Python documentation on `super()` says:

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class.

### Single inheritance with `super()`

`super()` is relatively simple with single inheritance, as shown in the **Inheritance in Python** section.

You commonly see it used in the `__init__` method for calling the superclass’s initializer with arguments supplied by the initializer of the subclass:

```py
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width

class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, length):
        super().__init__(length, length)
```

We define a class `Rectangle` whose initializer takes a `length` and `width` parameter. The length and width of a rectangle will be different. Next, we define a class `Square`, deriving from `Rectangle`. This makes sense because all squares are rectangles. Rectangles are not squares though because they don’t have equal length sides, but a square’s dimensions will always be the same. We pass `length` to `Square`’s `__init__`. This `length` parameter is then passed to the constructor of the superclass as the argument for both `length` and `width`.

`super()` is also good for extending the functionality of an inherited method.

I hope this message helped explain a bit on what inheritance is and accessing attributes/methods from the parent class, in the subclass.