# Mention outer classes in an inner class

Tags: python

How can I access an inheritance's list from an class inside of that class?

Hi I've been trying to create a chess board in pygame with pieces and wanted to keep things neat by having a "Board" class and in it, a "Chess" class that would contain all the chess specific code.

In the chess class I have a function (test) that assigns each square on the chess "grid" a piece.

How can I in the "test" function use the board's self.grid list?

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self.grid = []
        for y in range(self.size):
            for x in range(self.size):
                self.grid.append(Square(x, y, self.size))

    
    class Chess:
        order = ['r', 'n', 'b', 'q', 'k', 'b', 'n', 'r',
                 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 
                 '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 
                 '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 
                 '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 
                 '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 
                 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P',
                 'R', 'N', 'B', 'Q', 'K', 'B', 'N', 'R']
        
        def test(self):
            for square in self.grid:
                square.type = Board.Chess.order[self.grid.index(square)]
```

I want to be able to do this:

`board = Board(8) board.Chess.test()`

Comment: you can use `"Board"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access outer class from an inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024566/how-to-access-outer-class-from-an-inner-class)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly access attributes from the outer class in your nested inner class. For your use-case, you might consider passing the grid to your method call as an argument

```py
class Board:
    def __init__(self, size):
        ...

    
    class Chess:
        ...
        
        def test(self, grid):
            for square in grid:
                square.type = Board.Chess.order[grid.index(square)]
```