# Python Inheritance question

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have a class of boxes that need to move around in a grid, but need to access that grid's coordinates in its methods. I don't want my classes to inherit the grid unless they need to. Do I need to pass the grid to the classes as a parameter, or make the box classes inherit from the grid class? Thanks.

This is the edit. Let me clarify. The classes of boxes need to know the length and width of the grid. Therefore, I need to call inside the class functions like Grid.length() and stuff. I need it though, to give me the length and width of the grid that was created.

Comment: What do you mean by "access that grid's coordinates?" Do they need to know their own coordinates within the grid? Or some other coordinates?

Comment: Let me edit the question guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General rule would be parameter.

The question is is-a vs. has-a:

```
 Is the box a grid? 
     yes: # if so, then is it really a box???
         The box should inherit grid
     no:
         The box should get a reference to the grid 
            #(generally through a setter or constructor parameter).
```

### Edit

---

An example:

```
class Grid:
    def __init__(self,width=1,height=1):
        this.width = width; this.height = height;

    def getDimensions(self):
        return (this.width, this.height)

class Box:
    def __init__(self, grid):
        this.__grid = grid; this.x = 0; this.y = 0            

    def verify(self):
        width, height = this.__grid.dimensions()
        if this.x < width and this.y < height:
             print( "A-OK!" ); 
        else
             print( "I am off the grid!!!" )


grid = Grid();
box = Box(grid);
box.verify();
```

Comment: the box is not a grid, it is a ball inside the grid. So how would I pass it as a parameter?

Comment: Question: why are you using this? In 3.2, don't you have to use self._insertvariablehere

Comment: By "`this`" do you mean "`self`"?

Answer (score 0):

The box should reference to the grid.
However, with inner classes, you don't need to pass the grid as a parameter, with inner classes.
Inner classes is a Java feature, but you can metaprogram it to Python.

http://tomayko.com/writings/python-inner-classes

[What is the purpose of python's inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719705/what-is-the-purpose-of-pythons-inner-classes/722175#722175)

Comment: Does that speed up the process at all? Or would it be just the same as giving the grid as a parameter to one of the classes, then inheriting from that class?

Comment: well, because I am in a time crunch, I am not worried about speed, just that it works at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Since a box is not a refinement of a type of grid you should not inherit them.

You may be interested in the Acquisition pattern and [module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Acquisition). This allows getting attributes from the dynamic containment hierarchy, rather than static class (is-a) hierarchy.

Comment: It's not clear and I haven't tried it on 3.x. Try it and see. :-)

Answer (score 0):

From what you have said, `box` classes should not inherit from the `grid` class as this would violate the LSP.

See: [What is the Liskov Substitution Principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle)

The `box` classes should know how to query the `grid` for relevant information.