# Nested Classes in Python (PeeWee models)

Tags: python

I came across an example when searching for sample python code:

```
import peewee
from peewee import *

db = MySQLDatabase('jonhydb', user='john',passwd='megajonhy')

class Book(peewee.Model):
    author = peewee.CharField()
    title = peewee.TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = db
```

I can understand up to `title = peewee.TextField()`, but I'm a little confused with line `class Meta: ...`. Why is that needed? Isn't there another way to establish a connection?

Comment: This [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719705/what-is-the-purpose-of-pythons-inner-classes) might be useful.

Answer (score 3):

That is the [Peewee](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) ORM's way of specifying which database connection model classes should use. It's specified in a subclass so that Peewee doesn't treat it as a model field. More detailed information is available in the Peewee cookbook article covering [Database and Connection recipes](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/cookbook.html).

Comment: Yep -- it is a way of storing and inheriting "metadata" about a model.  Peewee uses metaclasses to do some interesting magic with ``Meta``.  If you're interested take a peek at the source.

Comment: For some reason there is no Cookbook in http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ anymore, so the link above isn't working..
[The last Cookbook I could find ist this (from v 2.0.2)](https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.2/peewee/cookbook.html). As I write this v2.7.4 is latest.