# Qualified name of exception defined as an inner class

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import typing

class A:
    def __init__(self, symbol: str):
        if not symbol:
            raise self.MissingException('Symbol (str) required!')

        self.symbol = symbol

    class MissingException(Exception):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A(None)
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 16, in <module>
    A(None)
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 7, in __init__
    raise self.MissingException('Symbol (str) required!')
__main__.MissingException: Symbol (str) required!
```

Could someone please help me understand why is the Exception named `__main__.MissingException` instead of being named as `__main__.A.MissingException`?

Thanks

Comment: Relevant [what-is-the-purpose-of-pythons-inner-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719705)

Comment: Consider class B which is a copy of class A in the same module. I would certainly prefer if the names were `__main__.A.MissingException` and `__main__.B.MissingException` instead of `__main__.MissingException` shown for both.

Comment: I understand what you want to accomplish. Extended your error string with `self.__class__.__name__`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, that would certainly distinguish between the exception messages. However, my curiosity with why the above behaviour was favoured still stands.