# Is this inner class usage correct?

Tags: python

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, no, laptop):
        self.name = name
        self.no = no
        self.laptop = laptop

    class Laptop:

        def __init__(self, brand, cpu, ram):
            self.brand = brand
            self.cpu = cpu
            self.ram = ram

        def AddRam(self):
            self.ram += 16



s1 = Student("John Doe", 41,Student.Laptop("Asus","I7 10950H",16))
print(s1.name)
print(s1.laptop.brand, s1.laptop.cpu, s1.laptop.ram)
s1.laptop.AddRam()
print(s1.laptop.brand, s1.laptop.cpu, s1.laptop.ram)
```

I'm trying to understand the logic of inner classes, if the usage is not true, how should it be?

I mean, is it right way to use the laptop parameter in outer class or it should be in the inner class ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need `Laptop` to be an inner class of `Student`, instead of its own outer class? Usually, inner classes represent sub-data structures that are dependent on the outer class to be useful (e.g. a `Node` in a `LinkedList`), not independent data structures that can stand on their own.

Comment: Sure, I don't see anything wrong with it. If `Laptop` is only meant to be used with `Student`, then it's fine. If `Laptop` is meant to be its own entity that might be used without `Student` one day, then maybe not. But nesting classes in Python is really just a namespacing and organization technique; it has no real effect on semantics other than how you refer to things. You may also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719705/what-is-the-purpose-of-pythons-inner-classes) helpful (avoid the first answer, though; it's a Java answer on a Python question for some reason)

Comment: Also, since you ask about correctness, it's worth noting that [Python's official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (and most Python programmers, for that matter) recommends `snake_case` for function names, not `PascalCase` like you have for `AddRam` (the latter is more of a C# convention).

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I want the laptops to be related with each student, is there any other way to do this or is it unnecessary ?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Thank you.. Yeah i usually use function names as you suggested, I couldn't understand why I wrote it like that here x)

Comment: I would personally just make `Laptop` an ordinary top-level class. You can define it in the same file as `Student` (Python has no restrictions on how many classes appear in a file). A nested class is really meant for cases where the inner class has no meaning without the outer class. GreenCloakGuy's node example is good, because a `Node` is *never* useful outside of the data structure it's in, whereas a `Laptop` can be perfectly useful without a `Student` (perhaps it belongs to an instructor, or perhaps it hasn't been sold yet and is sitting on a shelf somewhere)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232965/discussion-between-yigit-and-silvio-mayolo).